# Download MNIST data using vscode

Tags: python, mnist

Hi i am trying to download mnist data using these commands

```
!wget www.di.ens.fr/~lelarge/MNIST.tar.gz
!tar -zxvf MNIST.tar.gz
```

In simple a.py file using vs code but getting error . how can i run these commands in .py file

Answer (score 2):

Those are **IPython** commands that execute the system shell, not "Python". You'd need to create a Jupyter notebook in Vscode to use those as-is (but they still won't work on Windows, by default)

Otherwise, you need to rewrite both to [download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3) and [untar an archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893499/2308683)