# how to loop around every word in a line and then every line in a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictonary like

```
list1={'ab':10,'ba':20,'def':30}.
```

Now my input file contains :

> ab def 
>   ba ab

I have coded:

```
    filename=raw_input("enter file:")
    f=open(filename,'r')
    ff=open(filename+'_value','w')
    for word in f.read().split(): 
    s=0
    if word in list1:
        ff.write(word+'\t'+list1[word]+'\n');
        s+=int(list1[word])
    else:
        ff.write(word+'\n')
     ff.write("\n"+"total:%d"%(s)+"\n")
```

Now I want my output file to contain:

> ab 10
>   def 30 
>   total: 40
>
> ba 20
>   ab 10
>   total: 30

Am not able to loop it for each line. How should I do it? I tried a few variations using f.readlines(), f.read(), and tried looping once, then twice with them. But I cannot get it right.

Comment: That is a dict not a list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham : S sorry on not mentioning it corretcly, am naming that dict to be list1 in my code, and am retrieving the value from the dict.

Comment: You want to check if in a line there are some words and sum the value assigned to this words in your list1. Right?

Comment: @Llopis: yes, I want to sum it for each line in the file and print.

Comment: Am not able to print it for each line.

Comment: Please read [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 2 loops and not only one:

```
filename = raw_input("enter file:")
with open(filename, 'r') as f, open(filename + '_value','w') as ff:
    # Read each line sequentially
    for line in f.read(): 
        # In each line, read each word
        total = 0
        for word in line.split():
            if word in list1:
                ff.write("%s\t%s\n" % (word, list1[word]))
                total += int(list1[word])
            else:
                ff.write(word+'\n')

        ff.write("\ntotal: %s\n" % total)
```

I have also cleaned a little bit your code to be more readable. Also see [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) if you want to understand the `with` block

Comment: @charvi Don't forget to close the files if you are done with them

Comment: Yes, but we don't know if the OP wants to do something else with the f file

Comment: @Llopis : I have closed the files after manipulation. Thank u.

Comment: @MaximeLorant: thank u, n i think total=0 should be in the outer loop.

Comment: @Llopis He can still do it after the loops or rollback to the classic `open`/`close`. The `with` here is just to have a complete, correct working example ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving the answer right away, Let me give you a gist of what you ask:

To read the whole file:

```
f = open('myfile','r')
data = f.read()
```

To loop through each line in the file:

```
for line in data:
```

To loop through each word in the line:

```
    for word in line.split():
```

Use it wisely to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
 with open("in.txt","r") as f:
    with open("out.txt","w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split() # split into list of two words
            f1.write("{} {}\n".format((words[0]),list1[words[0]]))  # write first word plus value
            f1.write("{} {}\n".format((words[1]),list1[words[1]])) # second word plus value
            f1.write("Total: {}\n".format((int(list1[words[0]]) + int(list1[words[1]])))) # finally add first and second and get total
```