# Integrating Celery with Flask using the application factory pattern: maximum recursion depth error

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am working from the cookiecutter Flask template, which uses the application factory pattern.  I had Celery working for tasks that did not use the application context, but one of my tasks does need to know it; it makes a database query and updates a database object. Right now I have not a circular import error (though I've had them with other attempts) but a maximum recursion depth error.

I consulted [this blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern) about how to use Celery with the application factory pattern, and I'm trying to follow [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50666542/2066083) closely, since it has a structure apparently also derived from cookiecutter Flask.

Relevant portions of my project structure:

```
cookiecutter_mbam
│   celeryconfig.py   
│
└───cookiecutter_mbam
   |   __init__.py
   │   app.py
   │   run_celery.py
   │
   └───utility
   |       celery_utils.py
   |
   └───derivation 
   |       tasks.py  
   | 
   └───storage
   |       tasks.py    
   |
   └───xnat
          tasks.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
"""Main application package."""

from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('cookiecutter_mbam', config_source='cookiecutter_mbam.celeryconfig')
```

Relevant portion of `app.py`:

```
from cookiecutter_mbam import celery

def create_app(config_object='cookiecutter_mbam.settings'):
    """An application factory, as explained here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/.

    :param config_object: The configuration object to use.
    """
    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
    app.config.from_object(config_object)
    init_celery(app, celery=celery)
    register_extensions(app)
    # ...
    return app
```

`run_celery.py`:

```
from cookiecutter_mbam.app import create_app
from cookiecutter_mbam import celery
from cookiecutter_mbam.utility.celery_utils import init_celery

app = create_app(config_object='cookiecutter_mbam.settings')
init_celery(app, celery)
```

`celeryconfig.py`:

```
broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379'

task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
enable_utc = True

imports = {'cookiecutter_mbam.xnat.tasks', 'cookiecutter_mbam.storage.tasks', 'cookiecutter_mbam.derivation.tasks'}
```

Relevant portion of `celery_utils.py`:

```
def init_celery(app, celery):
    """Add flask app context to celery.Task"""

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

When I try to start the worker using `celery -A cookiecutter_mbam.run_celery:celery worker` I get a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` error.  (I also have tried several other ways to invoke the worker, all with the same error.) Here's an excerpt from the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 275, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 420, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 221, in run_from_argv
    *self.parse_options(prog_name, argv, command))
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 398, in parse_options
    self.parser = self.create_parser(prog_name, command)
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 414, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 277, in add_arguments
    default=conf.worker_state_db,
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 126, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 429, in __getitem__
    return getitem(k)
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 278, in __getitem__
    return mapping[_key]
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 989, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 126, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 989, in __getitem__
    if key in self.data:
  File "/Users/katie/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 126, in __getattr__
    return self[k]
```

I understand the basic sense of this error -- something is calling itself infinitely.  Maybe `create_app`.  But I can't see why, and I don't know how to go about debugging this.

I'm also getting this when I try to load my site:

```
  File "~/cookiecutter_mbam/cookiecutter_mbam/xnat/tasks.py", line 14, in <module>
    @celery.task
AttributeError: module 'cookiecutter_mbam.celery' has no attribute 'task'
```

I did not have this problem when I was using the `make_celery` method described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/), but that method creates circular import problems when you need your tasks to access the application context.  Pointers on how to do this correctly with the Cookiecutter Flask template would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved.  I had my `configcelery.py` in the wrong place.  I needed to move it to the package directory, not the parent repo directory.  It is incredibly unintuitive/uninformative that a misplaced config file, rather than causing an "I can't find that file"-type error, causes an infinite recursion.  But at least I finally saw it and corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspicious of that bit of code that's making the Flask app available to celery. It's skipping over some essential code by going directly to `run()`. (See https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/task.py#L387)

Try calling the inherited `__call__`. Here's a snippet from one of my (working) apps.

```
# Arrange for tasks to have access to the Flask app
TaskBase = celery.Task
class ContextTask(TaskBase):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with app.app_context():
            return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)  ## << here
celery.Task = ContextTask
```

I also don't see where you're creating an instance of `Celery` and configuring it. I assume you have

```
celery = Celery(__name__)
```

and then need to

```
celery.config_from_object(...)
```

from somewhere within `init_celery()`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Making your suggested change didn't fix my recursion error.  I'm creating an instance of celery in the main application init.py, which is what the SO example I was following did, and also what Miguel Grinberg's Flasky with Celery app does.

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like the problem is happening as Celery parses command-line arguments. What command-line is being used to start the worker?

Comment: `celery -A cookiecutter_mbam.run_celery:celery worker`.  In truth I don't understand that `run_celery:celery` syntax but I was copying it from the SO answer I mentioned.  But I tried many other more familiar variants (like `celery -A cookiecutter_mbam worker`) and got the same error. I've mucked with my code a bunch trying other approaches now (that still fail with circular import errors), but if there's something you think it would be good to try I'll put it back and run the worker another way.

Comment: The `:celery` part points the the celery variable in `run_celery`.  I might try cutting out all of the imports (i.e., make `imports = ()`) just to narrow the surface area down.

Comment: I took the imports line out of the config file entirely, and still the recursion error persists.  I really appreciate that you've taken the time to think about this.  I guess it's stubborn.

Comment: Short of seeing all of your source, that's all I have.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and engagement.  The problem is solved (see my following answer to my own question).