# SqlAlchemy and Celery structure Issue in python

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have two files:

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from celery import Celery
from resources.item import Item, ItemList, ItemInsert
from db import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = ""
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = ''
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = ''

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])

app.secret_key = ""
api = Api(app)

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()

api.add_resource(ItemList,"/items")
api.add_resource(Item,"/item/<int:id>")
api.add_resource(ItemInsert,"/items")

@celery.task
def update_row(data):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.init_app(app)
    app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```

`item.py`

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from flask import request
from models.item import ItemModel

class ItemInsert(Resource):
    def post(self):
        file_task = update_row.apply_async((data,), countdown=3)
        return item.json(), 201
```

As you can see in `app.py` I have imported classes from `item.py`, however now my celery (task) function call i.e `update_row` from `item.py` is left hanging, since I cannot import from app.py as it will result in a cyclic import. Is there any solution?

Comment: Move `update_row` into another module?

Comment: and then call celery from app.py?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/25408052/5320906

Comment: I did go through that link however it was a bit difficult to adapt to my structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple project, you could implement the tasks inside `app.py` as you're doing for now. But with more complicated project, it's better to move the tasks definition into a separated package so that it could mitigate the cyclic import.

Like so:

**App and celery configutation**

```
**# app.py**
# App & celery
# ...
```

**Tasks definitions**

```
**# tasks.py**
from project_name.app import celery

@celery.task
def update_row(data):
    pass
```

**API**

```
**# resources/item.py**
from project_name.tasks import update_row
# ...
```

Separate the tasks into another package (`tasks` package, which is [auto discovered](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks) by Celery) could help you to prevent cyclic import and also good to maintain the code.

---

But if you're still want to use the current approach, to prevent cyclic import, you could import it dynamically when calling API:

```
**# resources/item.py**
# ...
class ItemInsert(Resource):
    def post(self):
        from project_name.app import update_row
        file_task = update_row.apply_async((data,), countdown=3)
        return item.json(), 201
```

Comment: the line 'from project_name.tasks import update_row' throws an error saying "no module name flaskapp"

Comment: It's also depend on your PYTHON_PATH, maybe it's just `from tasks import *`, or you could set your project into PYTHON_PATH so that you could achieve it

Answer (score 1):

`celery_app.task` is a decorator, so just a regular Python function. It works in the following way: it takes your function, registers it in the celery app and returns a wrapper object with methods `delay`, `apply_async` etc. And you can always get a registered task from `celery_app.tasks` dictionary by its name. Another trick to avoid circular imports is in storing `celery_app` reference as an attribute of `flask_app`, and inside request context you can always get current flask app from `flask.current_app`

`app.py`

```
from tasks import register_tasks
...
app = Flask(__name__)
...
app.celery = Celery(app.name, ...)
register_tasks(app.celery)
```

`tasks.py`

```
def update_row(data):
    pass

def register_tasks(celery_app):
    celery_app.task(update_row, name="update_row")
```

`views.py`

```
from flask import current_app

class ItemInsert(Resource):
    def post(self):
        update_row = current_app.celery.tasks["update_row"]
        file_task = update_row.apply_async((data,), countdown=3)
        return item.json(), 201
```

UPD: indeed the most canonical way is to use autodiscovery of tasks:

`myapp/tasks.py`

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def update_row(data):
    pass
```

`myapp/app.py`

```
celery_app = Celery(...)
celery_app.set_default()
celery_app.autodiscover_tasks(["myapp"], force=True)
```

`myapp/views.py`

```
from .tasks import update_row

def index_view():
    update_row.delay(...)
```