# UnboundLocal Error onfile

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a problem with this file. When I launch it I get an error on line 24.

```
UnboundLocal Error : local variable 'file_out' referenced before assignment.
```

Any suggestion on how to correct it will be greatly appreciated. I have to say that I'm a complete noob on python and didn't write this by myself.

```
#!/usr/local/python

import sys, getopt
import os

usage="python correct_mol2.py -i 2qab_ligand.mol2 -o 2qab_ligand_new.mol2\n"

def main(argv):

    try:
        opts,args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'hi:o:')
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print usage
            sys.exit()
        elif opt == '-i':
                file_in = arg
        elif opt == '-o':
            file_out = arg
    x=0
    fout=file("%s"%file_out,"w")
    for line in file(file_in):
#       print line
        if line.find("@<TRIPOS>BOND") >= 0:
            x=0
        if x==0:
            fout.write(line)
        if x==1:
            if line[47:49] == '35' :
                fout.write(line[:47]+"Br"+line[49:])
                continue
            if line[47:49] == '17' :
                fout.write(line[:47]+"Cl"+line[49:])
                continue
            if line[47:48] == '9' :
                fout.write(line[:47]+"F"+line[48:])
                continue
            if (line[47] == 'H' and line[48] ==' ') or line[47] == 'F' or line[47:49] == 'Br' or line[47:49] == 'Cl' :
                fout.write(line)
                continue
            else:
                fout.write(line[:48]+"."+line[48:54]+line[55:])
        if line.find("@<TRIPOS>ATOM") >= 0:
            x=1
    fout.close()

main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `file_out` argument is *only* set if the `-o` argument is set.

You need to perhaps set a default before the `for opt, arg in opts:` loop:

```
file_out = 'default_filename'
```

If `-o` is meant to be a mandatory option, you'll need to explicitly test for the option being absent.

Other comments on your code:

- Use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) instead; `optparse` has been deprecated, it's successor is far more flexible and versatile.
- `file_out` is, when set, already a string. No need to use string formatting on it; you can pass it straight to `open()` (rather than `file()`, also deprecated). If you use the file object as a [context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) then it'll be closed for you automatically:

  ```
  with open(file_out, "w") as fout, open(file_in) as fin:
      for line in fin:
  ```
- You can use the file object as an iterator, meaning you can advance the file object and get more lines *in the `for` loop* as your parsing state changes. Use this to detect Tripos MOL2 records.

  [Tripos MOL2 data records](http://www.tripos.com/data/support/mol2.pdf) use tabs or spaces to separate the lines; split your line into columns, then pick out the specific column to map replacement values for. That's a lot less fragile than slicing the lines to specific columns:

  ```
  map = {'35': 'Br', '17': 'Cl', '9': 'F'}
  # when we encounter a mapped value, make it easier on ourselves
  # and map those back to themselves
  map.update((v: v) for v in map.values())

  section = None
  for line in fin:
      if line[0] == '@':
          # new section
          section = line.strip().rpartition('>')[-1]
          fout.write(line)
          continue

      if section != 'ATOM':
          fout.write(line)
          continue

      # parse the ATOM section
      for line in fin:
          if line[0] == '@':  # section end, we are done
              section = line.strip().rpartition('>')[-1]
              fout.write(line)
              break

          # atom data lines are whitespace separated
          row = line.split()

          # I'm assuming column 7 is the value you are replacing; adjust as required
          row[7] = map.get(row[7], '.')

          # re-join line with tabs, write out
          fout.write('\t'.join(row) + '\n')
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. 
The main problem is that I really don't understand programming. I don’t really know what to replace and how. 
I’m ashamed to ask you but can you rewrite the script so I only have to copy it and make it work?
I’m a scientist in medicinal chemistry so it will help my research focused on cancer.

Comment: @XavierDrozak: I only made an educated guess as to what might be done to improve your code. I cannot re-write your code entirely for you; I don't have the access to the data you have, nor am I in a position to test things for you. Find someone who can program or can teach you to program close by, in a setting better suited for mentoring. I am available as in online mentorship programs (see my profile). Good luck!