# load .mat file from python

Tags: python, matlab, h5py, hdf5storage

I am trying to run from Python a script in Matlab that run a Simulink mode, save a variable as Power.mat and read this variable in Python. I am using Python 2.7 on Windows.

I've tried to use the library hdf5storage to read the file:

```
import hdf5storage
x=hdf5storage.loadmat('Power.mat','r')
```

but I get the error attached.
[image: error]

Which could be the problem?
I have also tried with the library h5py but I get the same error. 
The file .mat seems not to be corrupted since I open it without any problem in Matlab.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this relevant?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287744/corrupt-files-when-creating-hdf5-files-without-closing-them-h5py

Comment: `x=hdf5storage.loadmat('Power.mat')` should work, although it takes forever to download the packages necessary to test it :)

Comment: Did you save `Power.mat` as a version 7.3 MAT file? Previous versions are not HDF5. From MATLAB: `type('Power.mat')` will tell you the MAT file version. Use `save('Power.mat', '-v7.3')` to specify the version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read .mat files in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You can use scipy.io to exchange data between Python and Matlab. There are functions named savemat and loadmat for this purpose.

Something like this should work:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('Power.mat')
```

For reference, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

Comment: There are four different `.mat` file formats.  The first three, `v4`, `v6`, and `v7`, are proprietary binary formats.  Those are what `scipy` can open. The last, `v7.3`, is a specialized hdf5 file.  That is what `hdf5storage` can open.  Technically it can be opened by anything that can handle hdf5 files, but hdf5storage has some tools to gracefully handle the MATLAB-specific bits.  Otherwise you get a pretty ugly (but still ultimately usable) output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
import h5py
Data = h5py.File('File.mat')
```

Comment: This is useless, it just gives me a bunch of hd5 reference objects. I can't do anything with them