# Have hdf5 designers resolved the corruption issue related to opening .hdf5 files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5

I am running a code which takes .hdf5 files as an input (produced by a simulation) and then analyze them and produces some statistics and plot through running the command line: `python3 Collector.py` in a Konsole shell of a Fedora 21 Linux. I have lots of `.py` routines in two different folders named `gizmo` and `utilities` in the working directory. The `snapshot_index.hdf5` files are transferred separately (using globus software) from another machine that runs the simulations into a local directory called `output` inside the working directory in my laptop. (There are many files corresponding to "index" running from 0 to 600 but I only need two such indices, eg. snapshot_396.hdf5 and snapshot_600.hdf5). Simulations are run in two different modes: low-resolution and high-resolution.

When kilo-bite size low resolution .hdf5 files are the input of the `part` expression (inside the main python code mentioned above), I am able to run the code and produce the results but when I am putting mega-bite size high resolution .hdf5 files as input of the `part` expression, I am receiving the following error message:

```
# in utilities.simulation.Snapshot():
  read snapshot_times.txt
  reading snapshot index = 600, redshift = 0.000


# in gizmo.gizmo_io.Read():
  reading header from: ./output/snapshot_600.hdf5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Collector.py", line 12, in <module>
    part=gizmo.io.Read.read_snapshots('all', 'index', 600, element_indices=None)
  File "/home/username/Desktop/Projects/PaperMaterials/DM_Dominated_Objects/NewFolder2/covering_fractions/Simulations/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 314, in read_snapshots
    'index', snapshot_index, simulation_directory, snapshot_directory, simulation_name)
  File "/home/username/Desktop/Projects/PaperMaterials/DM_Dominated_Objects/NewFolder2/covering_fractions/Simulations/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 513, in read_header
    file_in = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')  # open hdf5 snapshot file
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 222, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 79, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDONLY, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5f.pyx", line 71, in h5py.h5f.open (h5py/h5f.c:1809)
OSError: Unable to open file (Truncated file: eof = 933756928, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eoa = 1765865624)
```

I am not understanding the meaning of the error. But when I did a search on the topic, I noticed that this is not a new issue regarding `.hdf5` files ([Corrupt files when creating HDF5 files without closing them (h5py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287744/corrupt-files-when-creating-hdf5-files-without-closing-them-h5py)) except that the reason of not being able to open the file is different in my case. From what I understand (not sure if correctly), the files are too big and hence truncated. If this is the case, what is the solution for that? And if I am wrong then what is the issue?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your input file is corrupt.  What happens if you run the command-line utilities `h5dump`, `h5stat`, or `h5ls` on your input file?

I don't think your problem has anything to do with the designers of HDF5, or the other question you linked (which was about a program which crashed while writing an HDF5 file).  Most likely your writing program has a bug.   You can verify this by seeing if other valid HDF5 programs work with your files.

Your file appears to be less than 1 GB in size, which is not that huge for HDF5.

Comment: All three codes applied on the files give "error: unable to open file "snapshot_index.hdf5"" So, you are right; the files are corrupt. I just transferred them from a national laboratory super computer. That's why I doubted if they are crashed.