# Python script stops writing but in shown as a running process

Tags: python, performance, shared-libraries

I am running a python script on a screen on linux server and when I do TOP command I can see it running but it has been for hours that the script did not write anything. Anybody know what could be the reason?

Here is my script:

```
import GeoIP
from netaddr import *

gi = GeoIP.GeoIP("/data/GeoIPOrg_20141202.dat", GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
o = Path to the output text file

for line in f:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    asn,ip,count =line.split('|')
    org = gi.org_by_addr(ip)
    start,end = gi.range_by_ip(ip)
    ran = list(IPRange(start,end))
#    ipcount = len(ran)
    ip_start,ip_end = IPAddress(start),IPAddress(end)
    n_start = int(ip_start)
    n_end = int(ip_end)
    range = (n_start,n_end)
    print ("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s" % (asn,range,len(ran),org,ip,count) , file = o)
```

Comment: What is `o` that you use in `file = o` part of your print?

Comment: In is the ouput file. Not important

Comment: How do you know it hasn't written anything?

Comment: @Nick B cause the size +content of the last printed line of the file stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a few things; hard to say without seeing how you're running and how you're initialising that file.

A definite possibility is the file isn't being [flushed](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html) (more relevantly, see the docs on changing the buffer size of [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) as it's probably being invoked in your code).

Either way it's worth using Python (2.5+)'s `with` statement to handle file / resource management neatly and robustly instead of relying on `print` e.g.:

```
with open("/my/output/path.txt", "w") as out_file:
    # Rest of code
    # ...
    out_file.write("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n" % (asn,range,len(ran),org,ip,count))
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/) for good examples of using the `with` statement.

Comment: `with open("/my/output/path.txt") as out_file:` should be `with open("/my/output/path.txt", "w") as out_file:`

Comment: This solution will remove separate lines. how can I deal with that?

Comment: @Mee - good point -  needs a newline to keep it equivalent to your version, so I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to achieve this.

1. You can change your code to use the `with` statement (context
   manager) as @Nick B has suggested in his answer to open your file
   there.
2. Or you can set the buffering where you open the file to be
       line buffering.

So where you say:

```
# Im assuming you open your file like this since your code is
# an incomplete snippet. Otherwise tell us how you open your file
o = open('output_file.log', 'w')
```

You must say:

```
o = open('output_file.log', 'w', buffering=1)  # enable line buffering
```

You should read the help of then `open` command by typing `help(open)` in the interactive python shell. It explains a great deal how buffering works in python.