# Write row from sql server table

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am new to python. I can not figre out how to write a sql server table row to an output file. I can pt it on the screen but can't write it to a file.

```
import pyodbc
f.open(‘c:\python27\out.txt’,w)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL  Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=vzw;trusted_connection=True')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute ("select * from vzw.dbo.threcord")
row = cursor.fetchall()
print row  # displays row on screen
f.write     #what goes here to indicate the displayed row?
```

Comment: You can use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write out the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can output to a comma separated file by utilizing the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

```
import pyodbc
import csv

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL  Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=vzw;trusted_connection=True')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from vzw.dbo.threcord")
row = cursor.fetchall()

with open(r"c:\python27\out.txt", "w") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(row)
```

---

A few notes about what I've changed from your code:

- I open the file to write to only after the query has been run, instead of at the beginning of the program. Additionally I use the [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) statement to open the file.
- Notice that the file name is a raw string (with the `r`, because the `\`s are escape characters.
- The file mode needed to be quoted.