# Error writing over source HTML file after BeautifulSoup edit

Tags: python, html, windows, beautifulsoup

Here is my code:

```
#Manipulating HTML and saving changed with BeautifulSoup



#Importing libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Opening the local HTML file
site_html = open(r"C:\Users\rbaden\desktop\KPI_Site\index.html")


#Creating Soup from source HTML file
soup =BeautifulSoup(site_html)
#print(soup.prettify())


#Locate and view specified class in HTML file
test = soup.find_all(class_='test-message-one')
print(test)


#Test place holder for a python variable that should replace the specified class
var = ('Testing...456')


#Replace the class in soup redition of HTML
for i in soup.find_all(class_='test-message-one'):
    i.string = var


#overwriting the source HTML file on local drive
with open(r"C:\Users\rbaden\desktop\KPI_Site\index.html")
    f.write(soup.content)
```

This is the error:

[image]

How do I correctly overwrite the entire source file with a new file after the changes made with beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong syntax for that. The correct one is

```
with open(file, mode) as variable:
   # do something with variable
```

In your case it would be

```
with open(r"C:\Users\rbaden\desktop\KPI_Site\index.html","w") as f:
    #  I forgot 'mode' argument to open                ^^^^^^^^
    #f.write(...)
```

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012921/4354477) for more information.

The complete syntax:

```
with_stmt ::=  "with" with_item ("," with_item)* ":" suite
with_item ::=  expression ["as" target]
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html).

**Edit**: you're opening the file wrongly too. See the edits.

Comment: With the 'as f' I get this TypeError: must be str, not None

Comment: @RubenBaden, you're opening the file wrongly. See edits please