# Count the number of occurrence of pattern from lines in python

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to count the number of occurrence of multiple patterns from each line in a file. so if any of patterns found from line, I'd like to increase the counter by 1 so in the end, I can come up with the total number of lines that includes the patterns that I defined. but I'm stuck to search multiple pattern in a single line but increase count by 1 if found any patterns.
can anyone advise on this?
and can I make single pattern that covers three patterns I defined?

```
def sample_output(input_file):
    lines_detect_pattern = 0
    lines_not_detect_pattern = 0

    patterns =['HELLO\(L[0-9]\)\:\[APP*?\]',
               'HELLO\(L[0-9]\)\:\[Unknown\]\[APP.*?\]',
               'HELLO\(L[0-9]\)\:\[Known\]\[APP.*?\]',
              ]

    myfile = open(input_file, 'r')
    outfile = open(final_file,'a+')
    for line in myfile:
        for pattern in patterns:
            if pattern.search(line)

    outfile.write("Total number of system passed PMEM : %s \n" %pmem_pass)
    outfile.write("Total number of system failed PMEM : %s \n" %pmem_fail)

    outfile.close()    
    myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as pattern.search(line) is successful, you should increase a count and immediately `break` out of the inner loop.

So, something along the lines of:

```
if pattern.search(lines) 
 count += 1
 break
```

should do the work.

Edit:

Concerning the other question, since patterns are fairly similar you CAN include them all into one using [pipe operator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/operator/pipe). I **think** this would work but try it for yourself:

```
HELLO\(L[0-9]\)\:\([Unknown\]|[Known\]\)?[APP*?\]
```

If this (or a variant of this) works, you could remove the inner loop completely :)

There is also a great graphical tool to help you deal with semi-complex regular expressions called [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/), and a tool to test your expression online on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: pattern is a string, how is it going to search?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't use `pattern.search(line)`. `pattern` is a string and has no `search` method.
You need to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) or [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) (and then `search` method on compiled regex). It doesn't make any difference for your code. As docs say:

> **Note:** The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to `re.match()`, `re.search()` or `re.compile()` are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.

Like this:

```
import re
pattern = 'HELLO\(L[0-9]\)\:(?:\[(?:Unk|K)nown\])?\[APP.*?\]'

...

for line in myfile:
    if re.search(pattern, line):
        lines_detect_pattern = lines_detect_pattern + 1
    else:
        lines_not_detect_pattern = lines_not_detect_pattern + 1
```

For opening files you could use `with` statement. Read about it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) or in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` with your original code which will short circuit on any match, you also need to actually use `re`, `if re.search(pattern,line)`:

```
sm = sum(1 for line in myfile if any(re.search(pattern, line) for pattern in patterns))
```

You could just compile the patterns  first:

```
 r = re.compile("|".join(patterns))

sm = sum(1 for line in myfile if r.search(line))
```

A simple example:

```
patterns = ["\d+", "foo"]
import re

r = re.compile("|".join(patterns))
myfile = ["23", "foob", "bar", "hello world"]
sm = sum(1 for line in myfile if r.search(line))
print(sm)
```

Output:

```
  2
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for.. thanks for letting me know the use of "any". I was looking a way to find all patterns from single line at one trial so I don't increase the counter whenever if find one matches to pattern.

Comment: Do you want to match all patterns for the count to increase or any?