# Why do I get an "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write' " in this python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to  save the text in a beautiful soup object to a file, that I can later edit and use. I've got all necessary modules imported, but for some reason I get the same error every time at "pagename.write(str(soup))"
I've tried rewriting this multiple way and I am just stumped

```
#Testing implementation of writing to file
#save the HTML to a beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

#TODO: use breadcrumb of page name for loop later on
breadcrumb = soup.select('.breadcrumb span')
pagename = breadcrumb[0].get_text()

#open a file then write to it
bookPage = os.path.join('books/cpp/VST', pagename+'.txt')
open(pagename, 'wb')
pagename.write(str(soup))

#close file
#pagename.close()


#TODO: move on to next file
```

Comment: `pagename` is a string, not a file object

Answer (score 3):

`pagename` is a string - the filename extracted from the HTML.

What you meant is to use the `bookPage` path and a [`with` context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for). Plus, to avoid *TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'* error and to get a bytestring, you need to call `encode()`:

```
with open(bookPage, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(soup.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However now I am getting a type error:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @DakotaLorance okay, how about you call it `f.write(soup.encode("utf-8"))`?