# How to write the output of a os.walk to file

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a simple 2 line code and i need to write the output to a file. The code is as follows:

```
import os,sys
print next(os.walk('/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/'))[1]
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 you can use the `file` parameter to the `print()` function:

```
import os

with open('outfile', 'w') as outfile:
    print(next(os.walk('/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/'))[1], file=outfile)
```

which saves you the bother of converting to a string, and also adds a new line after the output.

The same works in Python 2 if you add this import at the top of your python file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Also in Python 2 you can use the "print chevron" syntax (that is if you do not add the above import):

```
with open('outfile', 'w') as outfile:
    print >>outfile, next(os.walk('/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/'))[1]
```

Using `print >>` also adds a new line at the end of each print.

In either Python version you can use `file.write()`:

```
with open('outfile', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('{!r}\n'.format(next(os.walk('/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/'))[1]))
```

which requires you to explicitly convert to a string and explicitly add a new line.

I think the first option is best.

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)** method to open file, write to [write](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to it and [close](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to close it as in lines below:

```
import os,sys

with open('myfile','w') as f:
    # note that i've applied str before writing next(...)[1] to file
    f.write(str(next(os.walk('/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/'))[1]))
```

See [Reading and Writing Files](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html) tutorial for more information of how to deal with files in python and [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) SO question to get better understanding of **with** statement.

**Good Luck !**

Comment: yeah i also thought so.. but this throws :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    f.write(next(os.walk('/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/'))[1])
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: try to wrap `next(...` with `str`

Comment: You don't need to call `f.close()` in a `with open(...)` block.

Comment: yeah works `f.write(str((next(os.walk('/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/'))[1])))`