# Show all Python variables in Abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

In Abaqus we can execute Python scripts. Using `globals()` or `locals()` we can list all current variables in the console. Is there a possibility to open a window showing all these variables within a table? Or maybe exporting them into an external text file?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/36965528/1004168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrated Abaqus Python development, called "PDE", is very helpful.
To open it from Abaqus/CAE, select `File > Abaqus PDE` from the main menu bar.