# I recently made an account making program, but I am not sure how and what commands to transfer a user's inputs to a text file. Could any one help me?

Tags: python, list

My goal is to get the inputs from users to go into a text file so that the users will be saved. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thank you!

```
users = {}
login = ""

def menu():
    login = input("Do you have a registered account(yes/no)? ")
    if login == 'yes':
        olduser()
    elif login == 'no':
        newuser()
 
def newuser():
    createlogin = input("create a username: ")

    if createlogin in users:
      print("\nThis username is taken\n")
    else: 
      createpassword = input("create a password: ")
      users[createlogin] = createpassword
      print("\nUser created\n")
    
def olduser():
      login = input("Enter login name: ")
      passw = input("Enter password: ")
 
      if login in users and users[login] == passw:
          print("\nLogin successful!\n")
      elif login == "administrator":
          print("\nLogin successful!\n")
          print(users)
      else:
          print("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password\n")
    
 
while login != "q":
      menu()
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at finding out how to do this?

Comment: You may want to look at [How to write dictionary to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965507/writing-a-dictionary-to-a-text-file)