# Exporting API output to txt file

Tags: python, fastapi

I have created a simple API with FastAPI and I want to export the output in a text file (txt).

This is a simplified code

```
import sys
from clases.sequence import Sequence
from clases.read_file import Read_file
from fastapi import FastAPI
 
app = FastAPI()
 
@app.get("/DNA_toolkit")
def sum(input: str):                        # pass the sequence in, this time as a query param
    DNA = Sequence(input)                         # get the result (i.e., 4)
    return {"Length": DNA.length(),         # return the response
            "Reverse": DNA.reverse(),
            "complement":DNA.complement(),
            "Reverse and complement": DNA.reverse_and_complement(),
            "gc_percentage": DNA.gc_percentage()
            }
```

And this is the output

```
{"Length":36,"Reverse":"TTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAT","complement":"ATATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCCCAAAAAAAAAA","Reverse and complement":"AAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATA","gc_percentage":5.142857142857143}
```

The file I would like to get

```
Length 36
Reverse TTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAT
complement ATATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCCCAAAAAAAAAA
Reverse and complement AAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATA
```

There is a simple way to do this. This is my first time working with APIs and I don't even know how possible is this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: huh he has provided the code though. Question can be summarized how do i write a dictionary to a file. Here are some options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965507/writing-a-dictionary-to-a-text-file

Comment: Don't use `sum` as [function] name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use open method to create a new file, and write your output. And as @Blackgaurd told you, this isn't a code-writing service.

**Also I wrote this code really quickly so some syntax error may occur**

```
import sys
import datetime
from clases.sequence import Sequence
from clases.read_file import Read_file
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/DNA_toolkit")
def sum(input: str):                        # pass the sequence in, this time as a query param
    DNA = Sequence(input)                    # get the result (i.e., 4)
    res = {"Length": DNA.length(),         # return the response
        "Reverse": DNA.reverse(),
        "complement":DNA.complement(),
        "Reverse and complement": DNA.reverse_and_complement(),
        "gc_percentage": DNA.gc_percentage()
        }

    #with open('result.txt', 'w+') as resFile:
        #for i in res:
            #resFile.write(i+" "+res[i]+"\n")

        #resFile.close()

        # Undo the above comment if you don't want to save result into 
        #file with unique id, else go with the method I wrote below...
    filename = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + '_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()).replace(':', '.')
    with open(filename+'.txt', 'w+') as resFile:
        for i in res:
            resFile.write(i+" "+res[i]+"\n")

        resFile.close()

    return {"Length": DNA.length(),         # return the response
        "Reverse": DNA.reverse(),
        "complement":DNA.complement(),
        "Reverse and complement": DNA.reverse_and_complement(),
        "gc_percentage": DNA.gc_percentage()
        }
```

Comment: You are saving the file on the API server. Probably, the OP needs to save it upon the API call from a client

Comment: Well I have no idea about the FastApi, so I really don't know, I've worked with flask. And as for saving the file on the client side, the OP can make the just raise a download request and the file will start downloading

Comment: I see. Pay attention to data modifications since that code overwrites the same file on the server upon each API call. I mean: someone could send another request to this endpoint before you download the file.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but that's going wayyy to far, OP can code it in that way, by writing an algorithm which will check the file if it already exists, then it would just assign a particular unique id to the filename

Ex- `with open('file_~uniqueid~.txt', 'w+'):  ........`

Comment: You might want to add this information in your answer.

Comment: I have made some changes with respect to your comment

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1={"Length":36,"Reverse":"TTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAT","complement":"ATATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCCCAAAAAAAAAA","Reverse and complement":"AAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATA","gc_percentage":5.142857142857143}

with open("output.txt","w") as data:
    for k,v in dict1.items():
        append_data=k+" "+str(v)
        data.write(append_data)
        data.write("\n")
```

Output:

```
Length 36
Reverse TTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAT
complement ATATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCCCAAAAAAAAAA
Reverse and complement AAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATA
gc_percentage 5.142857142857143
```

Comment: This is pointless because you had to write the output. You have created a dict and them generate the file with this dictionary. Do I suppose to create a new dict each time?

Comment: its just a sample we can take `res` itself

Answer (score 0):

I gonna assume that you have already got your data somehow calling your API.

```
# data = request.get(...).json()

# save to file:
with open("DNA_insights.txt", 'w') as f: 
    for k, v in data.items(): 
        f.write(f"{k}: {v}\n")
```