# Python filelock module behavior using `with:` statement

Tags: python, multithreading, with-statement, file-locking, filelock

I was just wondering about the specifics of python's module filelock and its behavior in a few circumstances.

First, how exactly is the `with:` statement handled by threads. If multiple threads call `with:` is it locked on a thread by thread basis? Is it also possible that two threads could acquire the lock at the same time?

Second, when I use `with:` do I have to clear the lock after its use? Is the lock automatically cleared after the `with:` statement is done?

Third, I have an instance in my code where I believe a file must be created then locked immediately. Currently I am using this:

```
channel_file = open(os.path.join('channels', username), 'w+')
with filelock.FileLock(os.path.join('channels', username)):
  channel_file.write(json.dumps({'rate': reobj.group(1),'time': reobj.group(2)}))
```

If there were a possibility that another thread could read the file since the time it was created, would this protect against that?

This also brings up a forth point. Does filelock lock read access while using `with:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The FileLock maintains a lock counter, which is shared across all threads in the process, and is protected behind a thread-wise lock. Every call to `acquire()` will increase the lock counter, and additionally will obtain the OS-level file lock when the counter was zero. Similarly, every call to `release()` will decrease the lock counter and unlock the file when the counter reaches zero.

   Therefore, if two threads acquires the lock at the same time, the file will be locked *once* by this process in the OS level, and the lock counter will be increased by 2. **The two threads will not block each other.**
2. The point of `with:` is to automatically acquire and release the lock after its scope exits. See [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for).
3. The file lock is used to protect against file access outside of the current process. It is not used for thread-wise locking. Use a regular [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) for thread-wise locking.

   ```
   # in __main__ or somewhere before we start the threads.
   channel_lock = threading.Lock()

   # in the worker thread
   with channel_lock:
       with open(...) as channel_file:
           channel_file.write(...)
   ```

For implementation detail you could refer to the [source code of `py-filelock`](https://github.com/benediktschmitt/py-filelock/blob/22154286b6014021d68f1e25bfa81c7b50e9a71c/filelock.py#L192).