# Calling a python to run a shell script

Tags: python, database, shell, beagleboneblack

I'm currently trying run the shell script by using the os.system method in python.

Python code:

```
file = open("History.txt","w")
file.write(history)
os.system('./TFPupload.sh')
```

Shell script code:

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST="ftp.finalyearproject95.com"
USER='*****'
PASSWD='*****'
FILE='History.txt'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT

echo ">>>uploaded<<<\n"

exit 0
```

At first, when i tried to run the python code and shell script one by one it works perfectly. However, when i attempt to use python to run shell script, instead of uploading the 'History.txt' file that contains data into the database, the file uploaded is an empty file. When i check using  'nano History.txt', it does contain data, only when it passes the text file to the database will be empty. Why is it?

Comment: You need to close or flush the opened file to ensure the contents written are written to disk.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use With statement to open files whenever possible .

```
with open("History.txt","w") as file :
  file.write(history)

os.system('./TFPupload.sh')
```

`with` statement takes care of closing the fd on its own .

some Ref : [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for)