# Mocking Method Calls In Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, methods, mocking, configparser

I have been searching stack exchange and around the web for how to do this, but I cannot understand how to mock behaviors for methods. I am trying to mock openpyxl behaviors and behaviors for my custom class. Here is my attempt:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import openpyxl 
from MyPythonFile import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_myclass(self):
    myclass = MyClass()
    wb = openpyxl.workbook()
    ws = openpyxl.worksheet()
    wbPath = 'wbPath'

    openpyxl.load_workbook(wbPath, data_only = True) = MagicMock(return_value=wb)
```

When I try the final line I get the error "can't assign to function call". Do I need to use `patch.object('openpyxl','load_workbook')`? I am used to mocking in Java with Groovy and it's pretty straightforward.

*Edit: wanted to add the finalized version of the test based on the response from @alxwrd

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import openpyxl 
import configparser
from MyPythonFile import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_myclass(self):
    myclass = MyClass()
    wb = openpyxl.workbook()
    ws = openpyxl.worksheet()
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    openpyxl.load_workbook = MagicMock(return_value=wb)
    wb.get_sheet_by_name = MagicMock(return_value=ws)

    config.sections() = MagicMock(return_value=['Section1'])
    config.get = MagicMock(side_effect=['Value1','Value2'])
```

Notice that config.get gives multiple returns with the side_effect parameter, so if `config.get()` is called once in the code it returns `'Value1'` and when `config.get()` is called a second time it returns `'Value2'`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't override a function *call*, but you can override the function itself.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide):

> ```
> >>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
> >>> thing = ProductionClass()
> >>> thing.method = MagicMock(return_value=3)
> >>> thing.method(3, 4, 5, key='value')
> 3
> >>> thing.method.assert_called_with(3, 4, 5, key='value')
> ```

So in your case:

```
openpyxl.load_workbook = MagicMock(return_value=wb)
```

Comment: Ok, great that works for the loading workbook, but what if I want to mock the same method but with different arguments and have it return different values? For example, if I mock `config = configparser.ConfigParser()` and then I want to mock `config.get('Section1','Value1') = MagicMock(return_value='val1')` and  `config.get('Section1','Value2') = MagicMock(return_value='val2')`?

Comment: You can access what arguments were passed with `.call_args`, and update what is returned with `.return_value`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value

Comment: Look up side_effect for a MagicMock object. You set it to a function, vs return_value which is set to an explicit value.

You can define the function with *args as argument and check it in the function body and return based on the args values.

Comment: What if production class is created 2 layers below test_xxx()

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to import the target you want to mock in your unit tests. Use [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) to mock the target. Let's assume your code has this import statement: `import openpyxl`. Patch then can be used in your test as a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators):

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from MyPythonFile import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('MyPythonFile.openpyxl')
    def test_myclass(self, openpyxl_mock):
        wb_dummy = 'foo'
        openpyxl_mock.load_workbook.return_value = wb_dummy

        myclass = MyClass()
        myclass.load_workbook()  # assuming this calls openpyxl.load_workbook()
```

*Note that you have to add an argument to the test method which will get the mock object.*

Or as a [context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for):

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from MyPythonFile import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_myclass(self):
        with mock.patch('MyPythonFile.openpyxl') as openpyxl_mock:
            wb_dummy = 'foo'
            openpyxl_mock.load_workbook.return_value = wb_dummy

            myclass = MyClass()
            myclass.load_workbook()  # assuming this calls openpyxl.load_workbook()
```