# Mocking Excel file content in Python with Openpyxl

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, openpyxl, python-3.9

The following is a simplification of a more complex problem, where I need to verify the contents of Excel files. I'd like to write unit tests for the functions I'll be needing, but ideally would like to mock these tests so I don't have to have a sample Excel sheet available.

The following function works:

*functions_to_test.py:*

```
import openpyxl

def read_excel_file_contents(filename: str, sheetname: str, cell: str) -> str:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)
    ws = wb[sheetname]
    return ws[cell].value
```

*test.py*

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

import functions_to_test


class FunctionsToTest(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @patch('functions_to_test.openpyxl')
    def test_read_mocked_excel_file(self, openpyxl_mock):
        wb = openpyxl_mock.workbook()
        ws = openpyxl_mock.worksheet()

        openpyxl_mock.load_workbook = MagicMock(return_value=wb)
        wb.get_sheet_by_name = MagicMock(return_value=ws)
        ws["A1"].value = "Some content"       
        self.assertEqual(
            functions_to_test.read_excel_file_contents("a mocked excel file", sheetname="somesheet", cell="A1"), 
            "Some content"
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_read_mocked_excel_file (__main__.FunctionsToTest)
Assert the correct contents of reading a mocked Excel file
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\markh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1337, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "c:\Users\markh\Python\Testing\test.py", line 18, in test_read_mocked_excel_file
    self.assertEqual(
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='openpyxl.workbook().__ge[45 chars]200'> != 'Some content'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s
```

I believe I have to use MagicMock() for this, but can't seem to figure out how exactly.
I've looked at [Mocking Method Calls In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941015/mocking-method-calls-in-python), but my case seems to go one step further compared to the answers given in there.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following modifications to `test.py` (please do check that everything makes sense):

Essentially, my idea was to make sure the newly initialized workbook `wb` has a sheet labelled `somesheet` using `.create_sheet`. Then, set `ws` as that sheet and finally set the value for cell `A1`.

**test.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

import functions_to_test


class FunctionsToTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('functions_to_test.openpyxl')
    def test_read_mocked_excel_file(self, openpyxl_mock):
        wb = openpyxl_mock.workbook()
        wb.create_sheet("somesheet")
        ws = wb["somesheet"]
        ws["A1"].value = "Some content"

        openpyxl_mock.load_workbook = MagicMock(return_value=wb)
        self.assertEqual(
            functions_to_test.read_excel_file_contents(
                "a mocked excel file",
                sheetname="somesheet",
                cell="A1"
            ),
            "Some content"
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer!
I'm trying to test your suggestion and if I change the return value of read_excel_file from `return ws[cell].value` to `return ws['A2'].value`, I would expect a failed test (or similarly, if I add `ws["A2"].value= "Some more content"` under ws["A1"].value = "Some content" to the test and call functions_to_tet.read_excel_file_contents(..., cell="A2"), it still looks for cell A1, so it doesn't seem to look for the correct cell in the test. Any suggestions?