# ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length using Python

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, project

Can some please help me I tried googling this error but could not understand why it is being raised. Can you point out the problem in my code I am fairly new to encryption this is my first time trying to use it.

> session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)
>     , ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length."),
>    ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.

**Encryption code**

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
random_generator = Random.new().read
print (random_generator,"HI")
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
print(key) 
code = 'totalyundetectable' #******************important ****************
encrypted_key = key.exportKey(format='PEM', passphrase=code, pkcs=8,
                          protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC")
with open('C:/Users/Arnav/Documents/Project/my_private_key.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(encrypted_key)
with open('C:/Users/Arnav/Documents/Project/my_rsa_public.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(key.publickey().exportKey())
with open('C:/Users/Arnav/Documents/Project/encrypted_data.bin', 'wb') as out_file:
recipient_key = RSA.import_key(
    open('C:/Users/Arnav/Documents/Project/my_rsa_public.pem').read())
session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
out_file.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))

cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
data = b'blah blah bl'
ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)

out_file.write(cipher_aes.nonce)
out_file.write(tag)
out_file.write(ciphertext)
code = 'totalyundetectable'
```

**Decryption code**

```
    with open('C:/Users/Arnav/Documents/Project/encrypted_data.bin', 'rb') as fobj:
    private_key = RSA.import_key(
        open('C:/Users/Arnav/Documents/Project/my_private_key.bin','rb').read(),
        passphrase=code)

    enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = [fobj.read(x)
                                               for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(),
                                                         16, 16, -1)]

    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
    data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)

print(data)
```

Comment: Produce a ciphertext with the correct length?

Comment: Tried that but I cant figure out how because its value is coming directly from the library function @LukePark

Answer (score 0):

In your case it looks like wrong [white spaces/tabs](https://appuals.com/fix-indentation-error-python/). Because if I write like:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

random_generator = Random.new().read
print (random_generator,"HI")
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
print(key)

code = 'totalyundetectable' #******************important ****************
encrypted_key = key.exportKey(format='PEM', passphrase=code, pkcs=8,
                          protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC")

with open('my_private_key.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(encrypted_key)
with open('my_rsa_public.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(key.publickey().exportKey())
with open('encrypted_data.bin', 'wb') as out_file:
    recipient_key = RSA.import_key(
    open('my_rsa_public.pem').read())
    session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
    out_file.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
    data = b'blah blah bl'
    ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)

    out_file.write(cipher_aes.nonce)
    out_file.write(tag)
    out_file.write(ciphertext)
code = 'totalyundetectable'

with open('encrypted_data.bin', 'rb') as fobj:
    private_key = RSA.import_key(
        open('my_private_key.bin','rb').read(),
        passphrase=code)

    enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = [fobj.read(x)
                                               for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(),
                                                         16, 16, -1)]

    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
    data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)

print(data)
```

I'm getting as result:

```
<bound method _UrandomRNG.read of <Crypto.Random._UrandomRNG object at 0x000001696F4B8700>> HI
Private RSA key at 0x1696FB5CE20
b'blah blah bl'
```

Also, be careful, if you're using the construction in code without [with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012921/8370915), you need to close file at the end.

E.g. in this case will be the error `ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length`:

```
#...

out_file = open("encrypted_data.bin", "wb")
recipient_key = RSA.import_key(
    open('my_rsa_public.pem').read())
session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
out_file.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))

cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
data = b'blah blah bl'
ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)

out_file.write(cipher_aes.nonce)
out_file.write(tag)
out_file.write(ciphertext)

#...
```

To solve it you need to write like:

```
#...

out_file = open("encrypted_data.bin", "wb")
recipient_key = RSA.import_key(
    open('my_rsa_public.pem').read())
session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
out_file.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))

cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
data = b'blah blah bl'
ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)

out_file.write(cipher_aes.nonce)
out_file.write(tag)
out_file.write(ciphertext)

out_file.close() # important to add at the end

#...
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
#...

with open('encrypted_data.bin', 'wb') as out_file:
    recipient_key = RSA.import_key(
    open('my_rsa_public.pem').read())
    session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
    out_file.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
    data = b'blah blah bl'
    ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)

    out_file.write(cipher_aes.nonce)
    out_file.write(tag)
    out_file.write(ciphertext)

#...
```