# How to handle an exception inside a with block

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I was reading up on how to properly use the `with` keyword in python, and I could not figure out the best way to handle an exception that might occur within a with statement.  So I am writing a very simple script to write a value to a file.

```
json = loads(response.read())
try:
  with open(args.file, 'w') as t:
    try:
      t.write(json[TOKEN])
      print "Wrote token to {file!s}".format(file=args.file)
    except KeyError:
      print "Unable to find {token!s} in response".format(token=TOKEN)
except IOError as bad:
  print "Ran into an error while trying to open file {file!s}".format(file=args.file)
  print "{err!s}".format(bad.message)
```

I want to be certain that if the KeyError is caught that the file will still close properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for)

Comment: "I want to be certain that if the KeyError is caught that the file will still close properly." - do you think it *won't* be closed with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the following document https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ that was in a link that was provided in the comments.

According to the link here is what happens when you use the `with` keyword.  In order to use the `with` keyword your expression must have an `__enter__(self)` and an `__exit__(self, type, value, traceback)` method.  Python will attempt to call the`__enter__()` method, followed by your block of code, and then run a finally with the `__exit(self, type, value, traceback)` method.  This will insure that that set up and tear down all get accomplished accordingly.  At least that is my understanding of the keyword.

Comment: Can you please summarize the solution? Link-only answers are discouraged on this site.