# Is there a way to automatically adding files into python with the title defined from a list?

Tags: python, file, automation, range

I am new to python and I was wondering if there is a way of using python to automatically make `n` files, define each file as `n.txt` and then write `n**2` into each file.

I have tried to think through this problem and came up with the following suggestion:

```
for i in range (0,100,1):
   x = open ("i%.txt", "w+") %(i)
x.write (i**2)
```

However, it returns the error:

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int'`.

Comment: typecast the int to string

Answer (score 0):

Try using `format()` and `with` to open and write to the file.

```
for i in range(0,100):
    with open("{}.txt".format(i), "w+") as file:
        file.write(str(i**2))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, however when I enter in i**2 it returns the error write() argument must be a string not an integer. So instead I used "i**2", but this didn't work as it printed i**2 into each file

Comment: Make sure there are no quotation marks around `i**2`. Also, convert `i**2` to a string before writing to the file. I updated my post.

Comment: Hi, quick question. I have tried to understand what the with function does... could you recommend any further resources to help me out? I have used the following: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: Check out this SO post about the `with` statement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for

Answer (score 0):

You can do it and are on the right track; you just need to format the filename string properly ("%s.txt" % i, "w+" or use str.format).