# Insert into table in sqlite3 and python. The magic of the "with" keyword

Tags: python, sqlite

I am following [this](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/create-tables/) sqlite3 for python tutorial.

I am trying to insert a row into a table with this script:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

sql = ''' INSERT INTO projects(name,begin_date,end_date)
              VALUES(?,?,?) '''    
project = ('X', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-30');

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql,project)

conn.close()
```

I can run it with no errors but the row is not inserted.

Although, the row is inserted when using `with`:

```
with conn:
    sql = ''' INSERT INTO projects(name,begin_date,end_date)
                  VALUES(?,?,?) '''    
    project = ('X', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-30');

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql,project)
```

Does anyone know whats happening?

**UPDATE**

I found in [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)
that after one or more `execute` statements one does `commit` as in

```
cur.execute(sql, project)
conn.commit()
```

and everything goes fine.

But still, I would much appreciate some technical explanation of `with` keyword

Comment: Have you tried to debugg your script ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean use the [`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) statement for debug your script and see what's happen...

Comment: No. I chosed to ask in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your date formatt... Who knows ? Without any error and any debug :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for)

Comment: Did you read my question? If not, please read this first: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But still, I would much appreciate some technical explanation of with
>   keyword

The reason why you should not `commit()` when using the database connection as  a *context manager* (`with` keyword), is because there's a mechanism that auto-commit in such case, if the transaction succeed (meaning that there's no exception raised).

It is explained in the [sqlite3 API doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

> ### Using the connection as a context manager
>
> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically
>   commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the
>   transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed:
>
> ```
> import sqlite3
>
> con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
> con.execute("create table person (id integer primary key, firstname varchar unique)")
>
> # Successful, con.commit() is called automatically afterwards
> with con:
>     con.execute("insert into person(firstname) values (?)", ("Joe",))
>
> # con.rollback() is called after the with block finishes with an exception, the
> # exception is still raised and must be caught
> try:
>     with con:
>         con.execute("insert into person(firstname) values (?)", ("Joe",))
> except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
>     print("couldn't add Joe twice")
> ```