# Can't do an if statement with data from a txt file

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic program that lets the user input a username and password and if it watches one in a file it outputs 'access granted' but the password won't match when compare with the file data even if they are the same

I've tried setting the data saves password as a variable however that hasn't worked

```
username = str(input('What is your username'))
password = str(input('What is your password'))
accountlogin = 0
file = open('login.txt','r')

for line in file:
   seperate = line.split(',')
   print(seperate[0])
   if username == seperate[0]:
      accountlogin = accountlogin + 1
for line in file:
   if password == seperate[1]:
      accountlogin = accountl`enter code here`ogin + 1
print(accountlogin)
if accountlogin == 2:
   print('Access Granted')
```

correct username so make it equal 3 it does so the password bit must not be working

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about debugging your code.

Comment: Why are you using two for-loops? You can check username and password in the first loop. Why don't you have your username and password encoded?

Answer (score 5):

Looping twice has two problems:

- After the first loop, the file cursor is at the end of the file. There's nothing left to consume. You could seek back to the start, but…
- You check that the username exists anywhere in the file, and independently that the password exists anywhere in the file. You should instead that they exist together in the *same* record. So put both conditions in the same loop.

Something like this:

```
username = str(input('What is your username'))
password = str(input('What is your password'))
accountlogin = 0
file = open('login.txt','r')

for line in file:
   seperate = line.split(',')
   print(seperate[0])
   if username == seperate[0]:
      accountlogin = accountlogin + 1
   if password == seperate[1]:
      accountlogin = accountlogin + 1
print(accountlogin)
if accountlogin == 2:
   print('Access Granted')
```

Or even just:

```
username = str(input('What is your username'))
password = str(input('What is your password'))
file = open('login.txt','r')

for line in file:
   separate = line.split(',')
   print(separate[0])
   if username == separate[0] and password == separate[1]:
      print('Access Granted')
      break
```

Also, obligatory note to **never store passwords in plain text**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a single loop like below.

```
username = input('What is your username?')
password = input('What is your password?')
with open('login.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
       user_txt, pass_txt, *_ = line.split(',')
       print(user_txt)
       if username == user_txt and password == pass_txt:
          print('Access Granted')
          break
```

`input()` returns str so, casting it to string using `str()` is redundant(not necessary). I'm also using the `with` keyword for opening the `login.txt` file. [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) this thread to know more about `with`
Next, we are splitting lines and taking the first two comma-separated string as username & password respectively from the line and ignoring the rest of the comma-separated strings in the line(if any).