# Why i get this error when i run the code? error= I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python-3.x

I am using open function to write a text file

I am using IDLE for code execution

```
File = open('abcd.txt','w')
for i in range(10):
    File.write("this is line %d\n" % (i+1))
    File.close()
```

my Expected result is

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
'''''
'''''
this is line 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `File.close()` in the first iteration. Any subsequent `File.write` calls will fail because `File` is already closed.

Use [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for):

```
with open('abcd.txt','w') as File:
    for i in range(10):
        File.write("this is line %d\n" % (i+1))
```