# Can an exception occur in a try/except statement without skipping the rest of the try clause?

Tags: python, try-except

Suppose the following code:

```
try:
    code_a
    code_b
    code_c
except:
    pass
```

If an error occurs in `code_b`, then it will be caught by the `except` and only `code_a` will have run. Is there a way to ensure `code_c` runs as well?

I imagine:

```
try: 
    code_a
except: 
    pass
try: 
    code_b
except: 
    pass
try: 
    code_c
except: 
    pass
```

is not the right way to go about it.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? If not what have you tried?

Comment: I think your only bet is to use multiple try statements as if any error is raised you will automatically go to the exception block. Maybe include error handling inside of each function of a, b, and c and determine the state based on the returned value, return -1 if error is raised and 1 other wise and compare all three values. I don't think you're looking for the finally block as it's not going to handle any errors raised, it's just calling a function regardless if exception is raised or not. I hope that helped!

Comment: Also another way of doing it but NOT a good practice is to use eval, so have a function that take cmd as argument and the body of the function is basically try  eval(cmd) except Exception pass, and have all your commands in a list and loop through them, this method can't be applied to all cases tho depends on ur program

Comment: Does `finally` do what you want?

Comment: also check out the `with` statement in Python (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012565/2480947). It's often easier than using a `try` block

Comment: @MarsilinouZaky I like your second idea! Defining a function with `eval()` in a try-except statement seems like a succinct way around this problem (though I think `eval()` can be nebulous at times.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to your title question is No. The rest of the `try:` block will not execute after an exception.

As you note, you can put `code_a`, `code_b` and `code_c` in their own `try:` blocks and handle errors separately.

You asked if `code_c` could run even if `code_b` raised an exception.

### Option 1

Put `code_c` outside the `try:` block entirely:

```py
try:
    code_a
    code_b
except:
    pass
code_c
```

But take care. `code_c` won't definitely execute. it depends what's in the `except:` block. Consider the following example:

```py
try:
    code_a
    code_b
except:
    return False
code_c
return True
```

If `code_a` or `code_b` raise an exception, `code_c` will not execute.

### Option 2

Use a `finally:` block:

```py
try:
    code_a
    code_b
except:
    return False
finally:
    code_c
return True
```

If `code_c` is in a `finally:` block it is guaranteed to execute whether or not there is an exception.

If there is no exception, `code_c` executes after `code_a` and `code_b`.

If there is an exception, `return False` will work as expected BUT `code_c` will squeeze in and execute just before the function returns. This is because it is *guaranteed to execute*.

### Complete Example

```py
def ham():
    print('Ham please')


def eggs():
    print('Eggs please')
    raise NoEggsException


class NoEggsException(Exception):
    pass


def spam():
    print('Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam!')


def order():
    try:
        ham()
        eggs()
    except NoEggsException:
        print('    ...no eggs :(')
        return False
    finally:
        spam()
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    order_result = order()
    print(f'Order complete: {order_result}')
```

When run as written, `eggs()` raises an exception. The result is as follows:

```
Ham please
Eggs please
    ...no eggs :(
Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam!
Order complete: False
```

Note that `spam()` (in the `finally:` block) is executed even though there is a `return False` in the `except:` block.

Here is what happens when `raise NoEggsException` is commented out or removed:

```
Ham please
Eggs please
Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam!
Order complete: True
```

Note that you get [spam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLih-WQwBSc) (and more [spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(Monty_Python))) in your order either way.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response! (As well as the "spam" history lesson) Your first line basically answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "finally":

```
try:
    print(1)
    print(some nonexistent variable)
except:
    pass
finally:
    print(3)
```

This will print "1" and "3"

Comment: I don't think that is the exact use of `finally`. Maybe you can execute it outside `try` block.

Comment: I think this is not what he asked. He is asking to run code c, d, e etc after having exception in code b. Finally is used like closing files etc.