# Creating a function that opens a file and extracts data to make a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary, file-handling

I have a text file containing this data and I need to make a function wherein this .txt file is opened, each line is read and then transferred into a python dictionary. This dictionary will have the first columns as keys and then the corresponding values would be both "Northings, Eastings".

```
Station Northings   Eastings
1   10001.00    10001.00
2   10070.09    10004.57
3   10105.80    10001.70
```

So far this is the only thing I have and it has this error when the function is called `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'`. Sorry I'm quite new to this.

```
def parsefile(file_name):
    station = []
    norths = []
    easts = []
    dict_station = {}
    with open(file_name) as fn:
        for line in fn:
            (stat,north,east) = line.split()
            stat.append(stat)
            norths.append(north)
            easts.append(east)
            dict_station[stat] = (north,east)
            print(station, norths, easts)
        
        return dict_station
```

Comment: I cannot recreate your error. Your code has errors though. Check for typos like using `stat` as a string variable and then trying to append to it.

Comment: @avatar-korra Do you want to have header row as a part of your dictionary?

Comment: @HetalThaker Could it be removed?

Comment: @avatar-korra Yes it's possible, i have updated solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error is that your trying to append to `stat` instead of `station`.

But your also doing a bunch of unnecessary stuff. This runs and is more efficient.

```
def parsefile(file_name):
    dict_station = {}
    with open(file_name) as fn:
        for line in fn:
            stat,north,east = line.split()
            dict_station[stat] = (north,east)
    return dict_station
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked now and I see why the other stuff I did wasn't needed.

Comment: I'd move the return to happen at the end of the function rather than the context `with`.

Comment: can i ask why should the return be at the end of the function?

Comment: Because `with` opens the file, does something with it then closes it again. It's best to let it close then return.

Comment: Some more reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for

Comment: thanks for the references ! i will read up on that

Answer (score 0):

As Station, Northings and Eastings have single value, instead of creating separate list for them try using below code here i am not considering first row to be stored as dictionary:

```
def parsefile(file_name):
    dict_station = {}
    with open(file_name) as fn:
        next(fn)
        for line in fn:
            temp = line.split()
            dict_station[temp[0]] = (temp[1],temp[2])
    return dict_station
```