# Django 3 test to catch ValidationError is not recognising the raised error

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm struggling to get my Django test to succeed.  The test file is as follows, I've kept it as simple as I can:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import Reporter

class NewReporterTests(TestCase):
    def test_reporter_name_should_not_be_empty(self):
        """
        Checking new reporter name cannot be empty and raises validation error correctly
        """
        blank_reporter = Reporter(full_name="")
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, blank_reporter.save())
```

The code which is firing the exception is in the data model as follows:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default = uuid.uuid4, editable = False, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.full_name == '':
            raise ValidationError('full_name is empty and is not allowed to be')
        super(Reporter, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

The output from `python manage.py test` is:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_reporter_name_should_not_be_empty (gallery.tests.NewReporterTests)
Checking new reporter name cannot be empty and raises validation error correctly
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/repos/django_play/gallery/tests.py", line 14, in test_reporter_name_should_not_be_empty
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, blank_reporter.save())
  File "/home/james/repos/django_play/gallery/models.py", line 17, in save
    raise ValidationError('full_name is empty and is not allowed to be')
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['full_name is empty and is not allowed to be']

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

So the test is creating a new reporter with a blank user name which should raise an exception in the save method of the model.  This does happen, but the test still fails even though (as far as I understand it) assertRaises should succeed, so I'm concerned I am misunderstanding something fundamental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of [`assertRaises(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) should be ***callable*** hence you should use **`blank_reporter.save`** instead of `blank_reporter.save()`

```
class NewReporterTests(TestCase):
    def test_reporter_name_should_not_be_empty(self):
        blank_reporter = Reporter(full_name="")
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, blank_reporter.save)
```

---

Alternatively, You can use [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) syntax

```
class NewReporterTests(TestCase):
    def test_reporter_name_should_not_be_empty(self):
        blank_reporter = Reporter(full_name="")
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as ctx:
            blank_reporter.save()
```

You can also use the [**`assertRaisesMessage(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRaisesMessage) instead of `assertRaises(...)` as

```
class NewReporterTests(TestCase):
    def test_reporter_name_should_not_be_empty(self):
        blank_reporter = Reporter(full_name="")
        with self.assertRaisesMessage(
                ValidationError,
                'full_name is empty and is not allowed to be'
        ):
            blank_reporter.save()
```