# What is the difference between 'open("file_path")' and 'with open("file_path")' in Python 3.8.10 and which one is most suitable to use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am studying Python and I found there are two types of file opening operations.
The first one is,

```
myreadfile = open("bear.txt", "r")
content = myreadfile.read()
```

second method is

```
with open("bear.txt") as file:
    content = file.read()
```

I want to know is there any difference between these two methods and which one is most suitable to use.

Comment: The with statement is called the context manager. It handles closing the file automatically for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## They are context managers.

### Explanation:

The `with` method is a context manager, if you use it for reading or writing I/O files, it will automatically close the file, don't need to add a line of `file.close()`, as mentioned in the [docs](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html):

> Context managers allow you to allocate and release resources precisely when you want to. The most widely used example of context managers is the `with` statement. Suppose you have two related operations which you’d like to execute as a pair, with a block of code in between. Context managers allow you to do specifically that.

### Examples:

There are examples in the [docs](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html), a regular `with` statement:

```
with open('some_file', 'w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write('Hola!')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
file = open('some_file', 'w')
try:
    file.write('Hola!')
finally:
    file.close()
```

It says that:

> While comparing it to the first example we can see that a lot of boilerplate code is eliminated just by using `with`. The main advantage of using a `with` statement is that it makes sure our file is closed without paying attention to how the nested block exits.

### A brief introduction of the implementation:

As mentioned in the [docs](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html), the context manager could be implemented with a `class`:

> At the very least a context manager has an `__enter__` and `__exit__` method defined.

As shown there, an example context manager implementation in a `class` would be something like:

```
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name, method):
        self.file_obj = open(file_name, method)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.file_obj
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.file_obj.close()
with File('demo.txt', 'w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write('Hola!')
```

The code can behave like a context manager due to the magic methods, `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

Answer (score 0):

The first one does not close the file automatically. The second one does.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the first one, you need to close the file after you're done with the operations while in the latter the file is automatically closed after execution of that indent block.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is the recommended method. This `with` syntax is known as a context and will automatically close the file once the context is exited as well as if something goes wrong during the operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the file is opened and read. It stays open afterwards.

In the second case, you use the file object as a so-called ["context manager"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). Special methods get called on entering and leaving the `with` block: on leaving, it is closed. This is superior to the other, even superior to

```
myreadfile = open("bear.txt", "r")
content = myreadfile.read()
myreadfile.close()
```

because the `close()` line isn't reached when `read()` throws an exception.

It is more like

```
myreadfile = open("bear.txt", "r")
try:
    content = myreadfile.read()
finally:
    myreadfile.close()
```

but easier to use.