# Can I read a FITS file in a single command?

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I am working with FITS files and to open a FITS file in the usual way I have to go through two commands:

```
hdu = fits.open('image1.fits')
data = hdu[0].data
```

Now I do realize that this is necessary in order to get the primary data of the FITS file from the header. But I was wondering if there was any way to convert it to a single command that would just get me the primary data of a FITS file just by mentioning the name of the file. (Or any other way to converting this two step operation into a single step operation.)

Comment: That's why functions are for.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer was very straightforward and I found it myself after thinking about it a bit. All you have to do it write it like this:

```
data = fits.open('image1.fits')[0].data
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can put the command in one line as such:

```py
data = fits.open('image1.fits')[0].data
```

Best practice is to use a `with` statement:

```py
with open("image1.fits", "r") as f:
    data = f[0].data
```

See [What is the python “with” statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3012488/5763413)

Comment: Though there's not really any sense in first assigning `data = None`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the other answers, but a more specific answer to this exists and it's [`getdata()`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/files.html#astropy.io.fits.getdata)

See also [Convenience Functions](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#convenience-functions).