# what is the differce between with open and f =open() in file handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('/content/test1.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')as f:
f.read()
```

**this does not gives an output**

```
f =open('/content/test1.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
f.read()
```

***but this works good ***

Comment: Both of them work if the indentation is correct. But neither would give an output except in specific cases in the interactive prompt. If you're doing it in an interactive prompt, wrap the `f.read()` calls in `print()` to consistently produce output. Or to store it, assign it somewhere; it's usually pretty useless to read from a file and not store the result anywhere.

Comment: It is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) for example.

Answer (score 1):

`with open` is using a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#context-managers). It means that within the block that follows, the `__enter__` method is called, then at the end of that block the `__exit__` method is called. Between those they are equivalent.

If you called `read()` on `f` within the block, you'd find the same behavior:

```py
with open('/content/test1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.read()
```

The nice part of the file context manager is that the `close` method is called for you.