# Modifying specific contents of a text file in Python

Tags: python

I want to modify `beta` and `n2` in `Test.txt`. However, `f0.write()` is completely rewriting all the contents. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
fo = open("Test.txt", "w") 
fo.write( "beta=1e-2")
fo.write( "n2=5.0")
fo.close()
```

The contents of `Test.txt`  is

```
beta=1e-1
n1=30.0
n2=50.0
```

The current output is

```
beta=1e-2n2=5.0
```

The expected output is

```
beta=1e-2
n1=30.0
n2=5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to read the contents of the file and store it on a dictionary, preferably using the [`with` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012565/9997212):

```py
data = {}
with open('Test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        # Ignore empty lines
        if not line:
            continue

        # Split every line on `=`
        key, value = line.split('=')
        data[key] = value
```

Then, you need to modify the read dictionary to the contents you want:

```py
data['beta'] = 1e-2
data['n2'] = 5.0
```

Finally, open the file again on write mode and write back the dictionary:

```
with open('Text.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in data.items():
        # Join keys and values using `=`
        print(key, value, sep='=', file=f)
```

Comment: I am getting an error: ```in <module>
    key, value = line.strip().split('=')

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```

Comment: You're probably finding an empty line at the end, try using the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Here an another example.

```
# get the data in the file
fo = open("Test.txt", "r") 
data = fo.read()
fo.close()

# Put the data in a list
stripped = data.split('\n')

# A dict with the data that you want to rewrite
modification = {
    "beta": "1e-2",
    "n2" : "5.0"
}

# Loop in the list, if there is a key that match the dict, it will change the value
for i in range(len(stripped)):
    name = stripped[i].split("=")[0]
    if name in modification:
        stripped[i] = name + '=' + modification[name]

fo = open("Test.txt", "w")
fo.write("\n".join(stripped))
fo.close()
```