# Text file Converter (replacing unknown words)

Tags: python, text, replace, converters

I started playing with Python and programming in general like 3 weeks ago so be gentle ;)

What i try to do is convert text files the way i want them to be, the text files have same pattern but the words i want to replace are unknown. So the program must first find them, set a pattern and then replace them to words i want.

```
For example:
xxxxx
xxxxx
Line3 - word - xxxx xxxx
xxxxx xxxx
word
word
xxxx word

Legend:
xxxxx = template words, present in every file
word = random word, our target
```

I am able to localize first apperance of the word because it appears always in the same place of the file, from then it appears randomly.

MY code:

```
f1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')

pattern = ''
for line in f1.readlines():
    if line.startswith('Seat 1'):
        line = line.split(' ', 3)
        pattern = line[2]
        line = ' '.join(line)
        f2.write(line)
    elif pattern in line.strip():
        f2.write(line.replace(pattern, 'NewWord'))
    else:
        f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

This code doesnt work, whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the world of Python!

I believe you are on the right track and are very close to the correct solution, however I see a couple of potential issues which may cause your program to not run as expected.

1. If you are trying to see if a string equals another, I would use `==` instead of `is` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504742/4470987) answer for more info)
2. When reading a file, lines end with `\n` which means your variable `line` might never match your word. To fix this you could use strip, which automatically removes leading and trailing "space" characters (like a space or a new line character)

```py
elif line.strip() == pattern:
```

3. This is not really a problem but a recommendation, since you are just starting out. When dealing with files it is highly recommended to use the `with` statement that Python provides (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) and/or [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/with-open-in-python-with-statement-syntax-example/))

Update:

I saw that you might have the word be part of the line, do instead of using `==` as recommended in point 1, you could use in, but you need to reverse the order, i.e.

```py
elif pattern in line:
```