# Average of numbers within a file with python

Tags: python

I'm learning how to use files in python, and I'm having a hard time understanding how to code them. My prompt is to assume a file containing a series of integers is named numbers.txt
and exists on the computer’s disk. Write a program that calculates the average of all the numbers stored in the file. I've created a notepad file called numbers.txt, and I put the numbers 5, 7, 8, 9, 20 all on separate lines, in that file and saved it as such. Here is my code down bellow.

```
def main():

    file_numbers = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
        
    num1 = int(file_numbers.readline(1))
    
    num2 = int(file_numbers.readline(2))
    
    num3 = int(file_numbers.readline(3))

    num4 = int(file_numbers.readline(4))

    num5 = int(file_numbers.readline(5))

    file_numbers.close()

    total = (num3 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5)

    average = total / 5

    print(f'The numbers are: {num1}, {num2}, {num3}, {num4}, {num5}')

    print (f'Their average is: {average}' )
    
main()
```

My output is

```
The numbers are: 5, 5, 66, 77, 220
Their average is: 86.8
```

Where is the computer getting these numbers? How can I change my code in order for it to output the correct numbers and the correct average?

Comment: As a side note, it's generally best to using a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) when opening files. See also [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3012488/11082165)

Comment: As a side-note: There's no need to hardcode the number of lines. You can do `nums = [int(line) for line in file_numbers]` to read any number of numbers into a `list` of `int`s, then `average = sum(nums) / len(nums)` to compute the average (without hardcoding exactly how many lines to expect), and `print('The numbers are:', ', '.join(map(str, nums)))` to print (again, without knowing the exact number of lines).

Answer (score 2):

```
num1 = int(file_numbers.readline(1))
                        ...      2
                        ...      3
                        ...      4
                        ...      5
```

That's just bizarre.
No, please don't do that.
The `size` argument specifies max number of characters
to read, not which line you are on.

Omit the arg, and life will be good.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline

---

```
    total = (num3 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5)
```

If you run this through the
[pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008)
[black](https://pypi.org/project/black)
checker, the "extra" `(` `)` parens will go away.

What's more important is you meant to start with `num1`
rather than `num3`.

To avoid such difficulties in future,
consider using a datastructure like
a five-element `list`.

For example, having constructed

```
    lst = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]
```

we can conveniently refer to `sum(lst)`.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely misunderstood how to use "num1 = int(file_numbers.readline(1))" 100%. I appreciate the feedback and help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple two-liner:

> Note: requires Python 3.8+ due to the walrus `:=` operator

```py
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    average = sum(lines := [int(l) for l in f]) / len(lines)
```

Print out results with:

```
print(f'The numbers are: {", ".join(map(str, lines))}')
print(f'Their average is: {average}')
```

Then we have:

```
The numbers are: 5, 7, 8, 9, 20
Their average is: 9.8
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a couple of edits to (1) close the file when we're done with it and (2) make the code able to handle any amount of numbers in the text file.

```
def main():
    numbers = []
    with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file_numbers:
        # using a context manager automatically closes the file at the end of the `with` block

        for line in file_numbers:
            # iterate through each line in the file
            # adding each number to the end of the numbers list
            number = int(line)
            numbers.append(number)

    total = sum(numbers)
    average = total / len(numbers) # use the length of the numbers list as the divisor

    print(f'The numbers are: {numbers}')
    print(f'Their average is: {average}')

main()
```

##### Output

```
The numbers are: [5, 7, 8, 9, 20]
Their average is: 9.8
```