# python reading only first line of text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very noob question:
I am trying to get the function to return me a number and the relevant line in a tuple.
Something like [1, hello] [2, world] etc for each line of the text file, but i can only get it to work on the first line.

My bet is that it is iterating over the loop only once, but i can't understand why.

**this is what I have so far, and this is giving me [1, first line of my file] and that's it**

```py
def read_word_file(filename): 
    
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        list_of_lines = file.readlines()
        index = 0
        cleaned_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in list_of_lines]
        index += 1
        tuple_of_index_and_line = [index , cleaned_lines[index]]

    return tuple_of_index_and_line
print (read_word_file(r"handins\british-english"))
```

Comment: _My bet is that it is iterating over the loop only once_ What loop?  There is no loop.

Comment: "My bet is that it is iterating over the loop only once, but i can't understand why." - where the code says `tuple_of_index_and_line = [index , cleaned_lines[index]]`, what do you think this means? How many times do you think **this line of code** should run, and **why**? Aside from that: where the code says `return tuple_of_index_and_line`, what do you think this means? Do you understand, that a function **stops doing more work** when it encounters `return`? "Something like [1, hello] [2, world] etc for each line of the text file" - think carefully: **how should the data be structured**?

Answer (score 2):

> My bet is that it is iterating over the loop only once, but i can't understand why.

You don't have any loop in your code.

Maybe you have mistaken the 'with' statement for a `loop` because of the `indentation`. You can learn more about what the `with` statement does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for)

You can add a `for` loop to fix it.

- You can follow your current index using `enumerate` instead of creating your own variable:

```py
def read_word_file(filename): 
    
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:        
        index_line_list = []
        for idx, line in enumerate(file):
            index_line_list.append((idx + 1, line.strip()))

    return index_line_list

print (read_word_file(r"w.txt"))
```

**output:**

```
[(1, 'first line'), (2, 'second line'), (3, 'third line')]
```

This function returns a list of tuples of index, line.

---

A more pythonic way is to use:

```
def read_word_file(filename): 
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return list(enumerate(map(str.strip, file), 1))
```

** Thanks to [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) and to [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) for the edit suggestions

---

In addition,

> tuple_of_index_and_line = [index , cleaned_lines[index]]

this line creates a list not a tuple. You can read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-list-and-tuple/) about the differences between tuples and lists in python.

---

You can also take a look in [*Read a file line by line in Python*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/)

Comment: There is no reason for the loop at all. `index_line_list = list(enumerate(cleaned_lines, 1))` would achieve the desired effect directly. And drop the `.readlines()` (which does nothing but make a pointless temporary `list` when you could iterate the file directly).

Comment: One more: `return list(enumerate(map(str.strip, file), 1))`

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yeah, but I'm assuming they want to keep other whitespace, which `map` won't do (not without getting `operator.methodcaller` involved, at which point, genexpr is simpler).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Do you mean because the question used `line.rstrip('\n')`? I hadn't noticed that this answer deviated from that, it had already used just `strip()` in a list comp. Why/how `methodcaller`, though? If I wanted to keep using `map`, I'd use `map(str.rstrip, file, repeat('\n'))`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yeah, that also works. Same basic idea, it's just reaching the point where I wouldn't bother, I'd just stick with the genexpr.

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop in your code. You can use list comprehension to iterate the lines that `readlines` produces.

```
def read_word_file(filename): 
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return [(i, line.rstrip('\n')) for i, line in enumerate(file.readlines())]

print (read_word_file(r"w.txt"))
```

It doesn't really make sense to store a line number, when it's index in the `list` is the same number. An alternate route you could take is simply this:

```
def read_word_file(filename): 
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return file.read().split('\n')
```

If your file is huge, the above method is not recommended.

Comment: `readlines` is *not* a generator. It's the single dumbest API they didn't remove from Py3; it returns a `list` of the lines, not a generator at all, equivalent to just calling `list(file)`. Your version of the code would be made better by dropping the `.readlines()` entirely (avoiding an entirely pointless temporary `list` in favor of directly iterating the file object, which *is* an iterator producing lines).

Comment: Didn't downvote a thing. I just have a pet peeve about people using `readlines` (and claiming it is something it isn't).