# How to empty a file using Python

Tags: python

In the Unix shell I can do this to empty a file:

```
cd /the/file/directory/
:> thefile.ext
```

How would I go about doing this in Python?

Is `os.system` the way here, I wouldn't know how since I would have to send 2 actions after each other i.e. the `cd` and then the `:>`.

Comment: Shouldn't opening the file with a mode of "w" do this, i.e. `open("/the/path/thefile.ext","w")`?

Comment: @Adergaard: I'm not prepared to claim categorically that there are no border cases (e.g. networked file systems) where it will fail. I don't know if you are in one of those cases, and had already tried, and it didn't work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to erase the file contents of text file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769061/how-to-erase-the-file-contents-of-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Opening a file creates it and (unless append ('a') is set) overwrites it with emptyness, such as this:

```
open(filename, 'w').close()
```

Comment: Would there be a problem if the file is constantly written to (it is a log file that is written to every second)

Comment: @Adergaard Typically not. If the file is already existing, it will not be created, but the same file will be used and truncated. If the logging process continues to write to the file, it will also appear in that file then. However, in combination with file operations based on `seek` or `tell`, weird things may happen.

Comment: weird, this just seems not to be the case.

Comment: Didn't work for me when rewriting file in a for loop. I used os.remove("filename") and then file1 = open("filename", "w")

Answer (score 42):

Alternate form of the answer by @rumpel

```
with open(filename, 'w'): pass
```