# How do I overwrite the text in a file using python3 so that the user can write more with out it interfering with old text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm confused and don't know what to do about this. I'm trying to overwrite the files text.

Comment: just open file with w flag?

Comment: Please consider providing some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914277/how-to-empty-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

when opening a file with `'w'` flag, it will rewrite the file if it exists.

```
with open('yourfile.ext', 'wt') as fileObj:
    fileObj.write(stuff)
```