# How do you clear a file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, operating-system

Does anyone know how to clear a file's contents on python?
Thank you.

Comment: As in, replace the data of a file with essentially nothing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to erase the file contents of text file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769061/how-to-erase-the-file-contents-of-text-file-in-python)

Comment: yes thank you it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file creates it and (unless append ('a') is set) overwrites it with emptyness, such as this:

```
open(filename, 'w').close()
```

See: [How to empty a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914277/how-to-empty-a-file-using-python/4914288#4914288)

Answer (score 0):

You can use truncate function on the file object:

```
file_object = open('test.txt','r+')
file_object.truncate()
file_object.close()
```

Comment: Thank you @Vishal Yadav but i have solved this already :)