# How do I clear a .txt file with the open() function?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a simple program which opens a file and replaces text. However, I want the program to clear the file, then save what needs to be saved.

How do I do that? Or is there a simpler way to do so?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have attempted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to erase the file contents of text file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769061/how-to-erase-the-file-contents-of-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the file with mode `w` it will overwrite the file if it already exists:

```
with open('your_file', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Some text\n')
```

This would create a file named `your_file` and write to it. If the file already exists, and you have permission to do so, it will overwrite the existing file.

You might also notice that I used `open()` within a `with` statement (context manager). This ensures that the file will be properly closed when execution leaves the scope of the context manager.

Comment: Is calling the `write` function - e.g. `f.write('')` - necessary if I wanted to clear the contents of the file?

Comment: @DerekKwok: No, just opening the file is sufficient to clear the file.

Answer (score 8):

When you open a file in 'w' mode, it's content would be erased.

> from doc - 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name
>   will be erased)

Just open file as

```
open(file, 'w')
```

Answer (score -1):

when opening in write mode, you clear the text in the file.

```
with open() as f:
    f.write("")
```

that'll fix it for you!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't open a file in write mode. It isn't even opening a file at all.