# How do I clear all the contents of my file before I write on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to delete all the contents of my file first, then write on it. How do I do that with a simple file? `

```
fileHandle = open("file.txt","w")
fileHandle.write(randomVar)
fileHandle.close()
```

Comment: yep, that'll do it

Comment: Opening a file with the `"w"` mode will already truncate it to the beginning.

Comment: This code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to open the file in a *truncating* mode. These are "w" and "w+". Your current code uses "w", so it should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
open('file.txt', 'w').close()
```

Or alternatively, if you have already an opened file:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r+')
f.truncate(0) # need '0' when using r+
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2769090/17773920

Answer (score 0):

whenever using `open(filename,'w')` all the content of the data will be overwritten.

If you wish to add content to the file you should be using `open(filename,'a')`.

In addition, I would recommend opening the file using

`with open('filename','mode') as f: your code here`

as it will provide context manager, making sure the file will closed when you are done with it.