# How to do force remove in Python like rm -rf on Linux?

Tags: python

I want to remove some log files of my App server without shutting down my server. What command can I use to do this using Python, like `rm -rf` in Linux systems?

Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Python library reference](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os)?

Comment: 'force' remove? Did you have any problems with code that didn't work?

Comment: HI i want to Delete log files using WLST

Answer (score 12):

shutil is your friend in this instance.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("/my/path/to/folder/to/destroy")
```

Comment: Does anyone else see the irony in this smug response when the top result in the Google reference is this very question?

Comment: While useful, `rmtree` isn't equivalent: it errors out if you try to remove a single file. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9559881/260491

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python             
import os

def nukedir(dir):
    if dir[-1] == os.sep: dir = dir[:-1]
    files = os.listdir(dir)
    for file in files:
        if file == '.' or file == '..': continue
        path = dir + os.sep + file
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            nukedir(path)
        else:
            os.unlink(path)
    os.rmdir(dir)

nukedir("/home/mb/test");
```

Above function will delete any directory recursively...

Comment: HI thanks for the Reply but the problem is i want to delete the Weblogic log file by using WLST with Pythan.

Comment: This seems like it should work for directories, but it isn't equivalent to `rm -rf`: it errors out if you try to remove a single file. Also, it's best to use the well-tested code from Python's standard library when possible, rather than writing your own. See my four-line `rm -rf` function here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9559881/260491

Comment: you don't need to write your own.  Python's standard library already has shutil.rmtree() which recursively deletes

Comment: Probably don't encourage usage of the word "nuke".

Answer (score 5):

Is your server running Linux, or is that just an example?

On python, `shutil.rmtree()` is the equivalent to `rm -r` (as @Alex already answered). All python removal commands (`os.unlink(), os.rmdir()`) work without checks, so they're always equivalent to `rm -f`.

But if you're on Windows, the OS [will not let you](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) delete a file that's still open; you'll get an exception. AFAIK there's nothing an unprivileged process can do about it.

Comment: HI alexis,My server is running on the linux machine. The Problem is i dont have permission to log in as Weblogic user. So I used to log in as the user who don't have the permission to delete the Weblogic log File. I am Using WLST with Pythan. IS there a way to delete Files BY using WLST.

Comment: No idea what WLST or Weblogic is. To delete a file, you must be able to run _some_ program under a process that has permission to delete it. If python's `os.unlink()` can't do it, there's nothing you can do in _any_ programming language: The OS won't let you.

Comment: While useful, `rmtree` isn't equivalent: it errors out if you try to remove a single file. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9559881/260491

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = 'rm -frv /path/to/dir'
p   = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
out = p.stdout.read()
print out
```

Comment: I'm reviewing some code and the developer used subprocess rm vs unlink. They were using unlink at first and then switched to `subprocess.call(['rm', '-f', file_path])`. I'm just trying to understand why they would do that, and if there is an increase in performance?

Comment: Because none of the built in methods to delete files or folders is reliable, even with all the workarounds you might find.

Comment: This could also work with the `os` module (built-in), and it works, but it's far away from "Pythonic code".