# How to remove the file or folder even if it is used by another process

Tags: python, file, operating-system

Is there a way to force-delete a file or a folder even if it is used by another process? I am getting on Windows:

`[Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: This looks like it may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766513/how-to-do-force-remove-in-python-like-rm-rf-on-linux

Comment: I have tried the solution from the the post to which you specified a link. None of them works for me.

Comment: Kill the process using the file.

Comment: The answer to this question may vary depending on the operating system that you are using. Is your goal to delete a single file that is causing you a problem or is it to write code that will delete files that have an open file handle? If you just want to delete the file once then you should grep the process list for processes using the file and then perform a kill -9 (nucelar) on those processes. If you are trying to write code that does this the answer depends on your OS.

Comment: I presume you are using windows?

Comment: It is running on Windows. Need to save the process that uses the file.

Comment: @Natecat but what if another machine is using the file? eg. the file is on a network drive. You can't kill a process on another PC.

Comment: https://www.technipages.com/windows-how-to-release-file-lock @TheoF

Comment: @Natecat I'm afraid I don't have permission to view 'Open Files': Error = 'You do not have permissions to see the list of files opened by Windows clients'. Even though I can manually browse to the file in Windows Explorer....