# Most pythonic way to delete a file which may not exist

Tags: python

I want to delete the file `filename` if it exists.  Is it proper to say

```
if os.path.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Is there a better way? A one-line way?

Comment: Do you want to try to delete a file if it exists (and fail if you lack permissions) or to do a best-effort delete and never have an error thrown back in your face?

Comment: I wanted to do "the former" of what @DonalFellows said. For that, I guess Scott's original code would be a good approach?

Comment: Make a function called `unlink` and put it in namespace PHP.

Comment: @LarsH See the second code block of the accepted answer. It reraises the exception if the exception is anything but a "no such file or directory" error.

Answer (score 821, accepted):

A more pythonic way would be:

```
try:
    os.remove(filename)
except OSError:
    pass
```

Although this takes even more lines and looks very ugly, it avoids the unnecessary call to `os.path.exists()` and follows the python convention of overusing exceptions.

It may be worthwhile to write a function to do this for you:

```
import os, errno

def silentremove(filename):
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except OSError as e: # this would be "except OSError, e:" before Python 2.6
        if e.errno != errno.ENOENT: # errno.ENOENT = no such file or directory
            raise # re-raise exception if a different error occurred
```

Comment: But would this pass if the remove operation failed (read only file system or some other unexpected issue)?

Comment: Also, the fact that the file exists when `os.path.exists()` is executed does not mean that it exists when `os.remove()` is executed.

Comment: @ScottWilson you can use the errno module to figure that out. (I will update my answer).

Comment: My +1, but overusing of exceptions is not a Python convention :)  Or is it?

Comment: @pepr I was just humorously criticizing how exceptions are part of normal behavior in python. For example, iterators **must** raise exceptions in order to stop iterating.

Comment: +1 because I can't +2. Besides being more Pythonic, this one is actually correct, while the original is not, for the reason kindall suggested. Race conditions like that lead to security holes, hard-to-repro bugs, etc.

Comment: @Matt, exceptions are not errors but just exceptional incidents; so raising one when an iterator cannot continue is just following this logic.

Comment: Just to say that precisely this is discussed here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#lack-of-fine-grained-exceptions

Comment: Is exception more overhead than if?

Comment: @liang: Performance-wise, yes. But maybe not noticeably for most Python purposes.

Comment: As of Python 3.3, you often might want to catch `FileNotFoundError` instead of `OSError`.

Comment: @stephan: According to the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove), `os.remove` still raises `OSError` and not `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: @Matt: sure, `os.remove` raises `OSError`. [Since Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3151-reworking-the-os-and-io-exception-hierarchy) this is a base class for various OS errors. But you no longer have to check `errno` to get more fine-grained information. Instead, it is possible to only catch `FileNotFoundError`, but not `PermissionError` or `IsADirectoryError`. As @Mr_and_Mrs_D already mentioned, [PEP 3151](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#lack-of-fine-grained-exceptions) uses exactly your answer as a motivating example. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @stephan: Oh, I see. `FileNotFoundError` is derived from `OSError` and it is actually `FileNotFoundError` that is raised. It seems the docs for the `os` library haven't been updated. Good catch! PS: I find it a little eerie that the PEP uses my examples letter-for-letter, even though it seems to have been written before I posted this answer...

Comment: Note that, if `filename` happens to be `None`, `os.remove()` raises a `TypeError`

Comment: I understand that this is probably the best way to remove a file, but I really hate using `try/except` clauses in my code except when absolutely necessary. It'd be nice if this were built into the `os` module.

Comment: @MichaelHays: That was my point when I said it "follows the python convention of overusing exceptions". It's the Python style of doing things, and it's built into the language relatively efficiently.

Comment: @Matt I'm not saying that this isn't an acceptable answer, just that I'm not going to use it out of personal preference.

Comment: This does confuse some potentially useful cases, such as an OSError being raised when the file is in use by another application (which just happened to me!)

Comment: @jellyberg: The second version that checks the error code should work, no?

Comment: isn't OSError a bit general? Wouldn't FileNotFoundError do it?

Comment: How about using `shutil.rmtree(path)` if it is a folder and use `os.remove(filename)` if it is a file

Comment: I like the function `silentremove` but I'm renaming it to `remove_existing`

Comment: Even if the file exists, the caller may not have the permissions to delete it. Race conditions aside, checking for existence is no guarantee of successful deletion.

Comment: Unfortunately people way overuse exceptions, which as you noted yourself is ugly not readable and essentially does not what asked. The task was "delete file which might not exist"while the implementation does "delete no matter what and ignore the error.  Now if the file does exist but could not be deleted for any other reason the operation will fail silently. See you just introduced a hard to find bug out of nothing.

Comment: It does not create python error but it still displays `cmd` error.

Answer (score 276):

I prefer to suppress an exception rather than checking for the file's existence, to avoid a [TOCTTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOCTTOU) bug.  Matt's answer is a good example of this, but we can simplify it slightly under Python 3, using [`contextlib.suppress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.suppress(FileNotFoundError):
    os.remove(filename)
```

If `filename` is a `pathlib.Path` object instead of a string, we can call its [`.unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink) method instead of using `os.remove()`.  In my experience, Path objects are more useful than strings for filesystem manipulation.

Since everything in this answer is exclusive to Python 3, it provides yet another reason to upgrade.

Comment: This is the most pythonic way as on December 2015. Python keeps evolving though.

Comment: I found no remove() method for pathlib.Path objects on Python 3.6

Comment: Not in Python 2.*

Comment: @EvgeniiPuchkaryov: Yes, I said as much in the last paragraph.

Comment: Perhaps to more clearly state, per the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink), `Path.unlink()` will delete ordinary files, or remove a symlink.

Comment: @jeffbyrnes: I'm pretty sure it's identical to `os.remove()` in that regard (as well as [`rm(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) and [`unlink(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink)).  Since this seems to be a pretty universal behavior, I'm not sure what you want me to add to this answer in particular that wouldn't also need to go on every other answer here.

Comment: @Kevin it was unclear to me until I went & re-read the docs, _after_ reading your answer here, that `Path.unlink()` also deletes regular files. Seems like maybe they should alias `Path.rm()` or `Path.remove()` to `Path.unlink()`, even if it’s just a convenience/clarity thing.

Comment: @jeffbyrnes: I'd call that a violation of the Zen of Python: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."  If you had two methods which did the same thing, you would end up with a mixture of them in running source code, which would be harder for the reader to follow.  I suspect they wanted consistency with `unlink(2)`, which is by far the oldest relevant interface here.

Comment: Yet another reason to upgrade to Python 3 - very true, even 4 years later.

Comment: I replaced the second line to os.remove(Path(chunk_name)) and got the code for removing a file if previously present

Comment: Can this solution be modified to do `something()` with the failing filename if the exception is raised? That is, can this replicate the `except` clause's functionality?

Comment: @nivk: If you need an `except` clause, then you should use `try`/`except`.  It cannot be meaningfully shortened, because you must have a line to introduce the first block, the block itself, a line to introduce the second block, and then that block, so `try`/`except` is already as terse as possible.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that unlike a try/except block, this solution means you don't have to mess around creating an exception in order to ensure that test coverage metrics are relevant.

Answer (score 132):

As of Python 3.8, use `pathlib.Path.unlink` with the `missing_ok=True` kwarg ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink)).

Otherwise, a try/except block is the best way to do it as it is thread-safe (unlike an if/else block that checks if the file exists). In Python 3.3, the `FileNotFoundError` was introduced as a subclass of `OSError` specific to the file not existing and in Python 3.4 `pathlib` was added as a cleaner way to deal with the file system. So...

```
import pathlib  # Python >= 3.4
import os       # Python < 3.4

# Python 3.8+
pathlib.Path("./dir/file.txt").unlink(missing_ok=True)

# Python 3.4-3.7
try:
    pathlib.Path("./dir/file.txt").unlink()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

# Python 3.3
try:
    os.remove("./dir/file.txt")
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

# Python 3.2 and earlier
try:
    os.remove("./dir/file.txt")
except OSError:
    pass
```

Comment: I use this in 3.8, but as `Path(filename).unlink(missing_ok=True)`

Answer (score 57):

[`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) returns `True` for folders as well as files. Consider using [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to check for whether the file exists instead.

Comment: Any time we test for existence and then remove based on that test, we are opening ourselves up to a race condition. (What if the file disappears in between?)

Answer (score 49):

In the spirit of Andy Jones' answer, how about an authentic ternary operation:

```
os.remove(fn) if os.path.exists(fn) else None
```

Comment: @BrianHVB Because ternaries are there to choose between two values based on a condition, not to do branching.

Comment: I don't like to use exceptions for flow control. They make code difficult to understand and more importantly can mask some other error occurring (like a permission issue blocking a file delete) which will cause a silent fail.

Comment: This is not atomic.  The file can be deleted between calls to exists and remove.  It's safer to attempt the operation and allow it to fail.

Comment: @EdKing That is true if the "exception" is actually a possibility. According to _PP_  the book, exceptions should be used for what really don't mean to happen, e.g. `/etc/passwd` don't exist.

Comment: @nam-g-vu Just FYI, I rolled back your edit because you basically just added the original questioner's syntax as an alternative. Since they were looking for something different than that, I don't feel that edit is germane to this particular answer.

Comment: Any time we test for existence and then remove based on that test, we are opening ourselves up to a race condition. (What if the file disappears in between?)

Comment: It's easier to write `if os.path.exists(fn): os.remove(fn)`

Answer (score 22):

```
if os.path.exists(filename): os.remove(filename)
```

is a one-liner.

Many of you may disagree - possibly for reasons like considering the proposed use of ternaries "ugly" - but this begs the question of whether we should listen to people used to ugly standards when they call something non-standard "ugly".

Comment: this is clean -- I don't like to use exceptions for flow control.  They make code difficult to understand and more importantly can mask some other error occurring (like a permission issue blocking a file delete) which will cause a silent fail.

Comment: It's not pretty because it assumes there is only one process that will modify filename.  It's not atomic.  It's safe and correct to attempt the operation and fail gracefully.  It's annoying that Python can't standardize.  If we had a directory, we'd use shutil and it would support exactly what we want.

Comment: This is OK for your private tool scripts.
This is NOT OK for servers.
reason being: race condition vulnerability

Answer (score 9):

[Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10840586/248616) is the right one for older Pythons and [Kevin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27045091/248616) the right answer for newer ones.

If you wish not to copy the function for `silentremove`, this functionality is exposed in [path.py](https://pypi.org/project/path.py) as [remove_p](http://pathpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#path.Path.remove_p):

```
from path import Path
Path(filename).remove_p()
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way to know if the file (or files) exists, and to remove it, is using the module glob.

```
from glob import glob
import os

for filename in glob("*.csv"):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Glob finds all the files that could select the pattern with a *nix wildcard, and loops the list.

Answer (score 5):

[Since Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3151-reworking-the-os-and-io-exception-hierarchy) you can use `FileNotFoundError` which is more correct than the accepted version since it doesn't ignore other possible errors.

```py
try:
    os.remove(filename)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

Comment: For those just copying the snippet, it should be:
`except FileNotFoundError:`

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.4 or later version, the pythonic way would be:

```
import os
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(OSError):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: This does not differ substantively from [the answer offered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27045091/148680).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Takes advantage of short-circuit evaluation. If the file does not exist, the whole conditional cannot be true, so python will not bother evaluation the second part.

```
os.path.exists("gogogo.php") and os.remove("gogogo.php")
```

Comment: This is definitely not "more Pythonic"—in fact, it's something Guido specifically warns about, and refers to as "abuse" of the boolean operators.

Comment: oh, I agree - part of the question asked for a one line way and this was the first thing that popped into my head

Comment: Well, you could also make it a one-liner by just removing the newline after the colon… Or, even better, Guide grudgingly added the if-expression to stop people from "abusing the boolean operators", and there's a great opportunity to prove that anything can be abused: os.remove("gogogo.php") if os.path.exists("gogogo.php") else None. :)

Answer (score 0):

A KISS offering:

```
def remove_if_exists(filename):
  if os.path.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
```

And then:

```
remove_if_exists("my.file")
```

Comment: If you have to write a whole function it kind of misses the point of one-liners

Comment: @Ion Lesan The OP is after the "best" way to solve this problem. A one liner is never a better way if it jeopardizes readability.

Comment: Given the inherently broad definition of "best", I'm not going to argue in this sense, although it's clearly affected by TOCTOU. And definitely not a KISS solution.

Comment: @Matt True but don't a number of solutions offered here suffer from this issue?

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103794/735926) from 2014, with the same issues.

Answer (score -1):

This is another solution:

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename)):
    os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is already covered in previous answers and is problematic because it’s not atomic. You may also want to use an intermediate variable instead of calling `os.path.join` twice.

Answer (score -1):

If glob is available.

```
list(map(os.remove, glob.glob("file/matching/pattern/*.csv")))
```

`map` to map the output of glob to `os.remove`.

`list` to invoke the map object. (Python3)

Comment: Use a loop instead. Using `list(map(…))` for side-effects makes the code harder to understand and wastes a little amount of memory since you don’t need the resulting list.