# deleting file if it exists; python

Tags: python, file-io, try-catch

I want to create a file; if it already exists I want to delete it and create it anew. I tried doing it like this but it throws a Win32 error. What am I doing wrong?

```
try:
    with open(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt'):
        os.remove(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt')
        f1 = open(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt', 'a')
except IOError:
    f1 = open(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most pythonic way to delete a file which may not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840533/most-pythonic-way-to-delete-a-file-which-may-not-exist)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're trying to delete an open file, and the docs for [`os.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) state...

> On Windows, attempting to remove a file that is in use causes an exception to be raised

You could change the code to...

```
filename = os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt'
try:
    os.remove(filename)
except OSError:
    pass
f1 = open(filename, 'a')
```

...or you can replace all that with...

```
f1 = open(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt', 'w')
```

...which will truncate the file to zero length before opening.

Comment: This is a potential race condition, check `os.path.exists` before removing it that is

Comment: Another program may be operating on the file and deletes it just after `os.path.exists` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Oh yup it's fine now, I realized just after I wrote mine you could use `'w'` but I had that before

Comment: safer way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840533/most-pythonic-way-to-delete-a-file-which-may-not-exist

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to remove the file while it is open, you don't even need that `with` there to delete it:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop/input.txt')
with open(path, 'w'): as f:
    # do stuff
```

Deletes if it exists

Answer (score 2):

You can use open with mode parameter = 'w'. If mode is omitted, it defaults to 'r'.

```
with open(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt', 'w')
```

> **w**     Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
>             The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Yui I don't understand you said you want to delete it if it exists... Please update your question with no strings attached

Comment: Yes I want to delete it if it already exists before i start the script. After creating it anew I have multiple strings that get attached to the new file

Answer (score 1):

Windows won't let you delete an open file (unless it's opened with unusual sharing options).  You'll need to close it before deleting it:

```
try:
    with open(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt') as existing_file:
        existing_file.close()
        os.remove(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 from os import path, 
    PATH = os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt'
    if path.isfile(PATH):
       try:
          os.remove(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt')
       except OSError:
          pass
```

edited :

```
from os import path, 
        PATH = os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt'
        try:
            os.remove(os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\input.txt')
        except OSError:
            pass
```

Comment: potential race condition here as well

Comment: There's no race condition now but the `path.isfile(PATH)` has become effectively redundant

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would make the solution safer.In this case I think my solution will be exactly same as Aya.

Comment: It doesn't make it any safer as Aya's. Your solution just does two checks instead of one, where the first one doesn't help the security at all, only the second does