# RESTful API with python and flask to request and read a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to read a text file using flask framework. This is my code

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, flash,jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Welcome'

@app.route('/getfile', methods=['POST'])
def getfile():
    file = request.files['file']
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
    return jsonify(file_content)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')
```

I am using POSTMAN to check it, [image: pic]

unfortunately it sends bad requests 400. I requested file as `request.file`.
The .txt is residing in my disk at C:/Users/rbby/Desktop/Programs/hello.txt

The GET method is working fine. POST is not working for me. Is there anything else i should add from my above code?

I referred to this link [Using Flask to load a txt file through the browser and access its data for processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801728/using-flask-to-load-a-txt-file-through-the-browser-and-access-its-data-for-proce)
Do i need to add these lines too? I don't understand these

```
filename = secure_filename(file.filename) 

# os.path.join is used so that paths work in every operating system
file.save(os.path.join("wherever","you","want",filename))
```

Comment: what are you trying to is not clear, are you trying to send file for uploading or trying to send a file name using post method and return its content?

Comment: I want to read the content of a text file. I am sending a file name using POST method and want to return its content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that what you want `POST /getfile` to do is return the contents of the text file, then you can simply define your `getfile()` function as:

```
def getfile():
    file = request.files['file']
    return file.read()
```

Also make sure in Postman that you are setting the key of your file to `file` (as in the screenshot below):

[image: Postman screenshot, with key set to file]

**EDIT:** Note that the above method just takes a file and returns its contents - it does not take a **filename**, and return its contents.

Comment: The OP want to pass the file name and get the file content back. You just   return the content of uploaded file.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is pass the file name to the server and get the file content which might be stored on the server file system.

You shouldn't get the file name from the `file` attribute of `request`. It store the file content you uploaded.

You should just pass the file name through the key-value form or json.

```
@app.route("/getfile", methods=["POST"])
def getfile():
    file_name = request.form["file_name"]
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
    return file_content
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work. Have used Get here :

```
 from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Welcome'

@app.route("/getfile", methods=['GET'])
def getfile():
    with open("name of file", "r+") as f:
        data=f.read()
    return data



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')
```