# How to remove 'file does not exist' error in python 35

Tags: python, pandas

I was executing this code when i encountered this error related to file not found. 
File exists in the same folder where code resides, bu still this error is not going. 
Please help!

code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np

style.use('ggplot')
df= pd.read_csv('nse2.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
df_ohlc= df['close'].resample('10D').ohlc()
df_ohlc.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df_ohlc.head())
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1),(0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1),(5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
ax1.xaxis_date()
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,df_ohlc.values, width=2, colorup='g')
plt.show()
```

Here is the Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "F:\Report on Artificial Intelligence\candlestick code\c5.py",
>   line 13, in     df= pd.read_csv('nse2.csv', parse_dates=True,
>   index_col=0)   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 498, in
>   parser_f
>
> return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 275, in
>   _read
>       parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)   File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 590, in **init**
>       self._make_engine(self.engine)   File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 731, in
>   _make_engine
>       self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)   File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 1103, in **init**
>       self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)   File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 353, in pandas.parser.TextReader.**cinit**
>   (pandas\parser.c:3246)   File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 591, in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:6111)
>   OSError:

This is the main error

> ->" File b'nse2.csv' does not exist"

Comment: I'm still unsure at what i'm looking at, but this link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840533/most-pythonic-way-to-delete-a-file-which-may-not-exist

Comment: python doesn't look for files relative to the folder where the code is, it looks for files relative to your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you executed the script from in a different location other than the directory the 'bse2.scv' file is located.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use the full path, or change the working directory.

```
import os
os.chdir("/Users/foo/bar")
```

You can see your current working directory by doing:

```
os.getcwd()
```

Personally I find that using the full path is always good practice.