# How to remove folder in python? rmtree onerror

Tags: python, windows, file, onerror

I've recently have this trouble: I needed a function that removes an entirely folder in windows so I searched and this is what I get:

[How do I remove/delete a folder that is not empty with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303200/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-folder-that-is-not-)    empty-with-python

The answers, that looks ok, seems a bit confusing and large for me... there should be a better way to solve the oneerror while accesing files in windows with shutil.rmtree (raise an error trying to acces read only files)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I want to share an easy way that works for me.

I just made a function that changes the write permission mode of the file, and then deletes it with `os.remove`:

```
import stat # needed for file stat

# arguments: the function that failed, the path 
# it failed on, and the error that occurred.
def redo_with_write(redo_func, path, err):
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
    redo_func(path)
```

then when using `rmtree`, add it  to the `onerror` parameter:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(desiredpath, onerror = redo_with_write)
```

Hope it helps to someone with the same trouble I get.

Comment: How this method could handle if the directory is not exist, i.e. containing the   ```ignore_errors=True``` in itself.