# Deleting folders in python recursively

Tags: python, directory

I'm having a problem with deleting empty directories. Here is my code:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_to_search):
    # other codes

    try:
        os.rmdir(dirpath)
    except OSError as ex:
        print(ex)
```

The argument `dir_to_search` is where I'm passing the directory where the work needs to be done. That directory looks like this:

```
test/20/...
test/22/...
test/25/...
test/26/...
```

Note that all the above folders are empty. When I run this script the folders `20`,`25` alone gets deleted! But the folders `25` and `26` aren't deleted, even though they are empty folders.

#### Edit:

The exception that I'm getting are:

```
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10/29'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10/29/tmp'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10/28'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10/28/tmp'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10/26'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10/25'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10/27'
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/python-user/shell-scripts/s3logs/test/2012/10/27/tmp'
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: are you sure they don't have hidden files?

Comment: Is an exception or traceback printed? If so - it would help if you added that to the question

Comment: @Jeff: Yes I'm sure. In fact in my ubuntu machine I tried `rmdir /path/to/25th/folder` is deleting the entire directory. Which means that directory is an empty one!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove/delete a folder that is not empty with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303200/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-folder-that-is-not-empty-with-python) of both question AND answer

Answer (score 704, accepted):

Try [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree):

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/path/to/your/dir/')
```

Comment: Does the `rmtree` deleted the entire directory? I guess it is similar to the one `rm -Rf $DIR`

Comment: Be careful as rmtree deletes the files too. As asked, the question was how to delete EMPTY directories.The docs for os.walk give an example that almost exactly matches this question:  
`import os
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):  
      for name in dirs:  
         os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))  
`

Comment: is there something wrong witht his solution? why are there more answers needed ? :/

Comment: @CharlieParker - there's nothing wrong with this answer. The reason for other answers is sometimes people maybe don't know the idiomatic way of doing something or they have a specific reason/use case not to use the idiomatic way, or, they want to highlight a different approach for whatever reason. If you want to dig in then you should open a new question.

Answer (score 45):

Here's my pure [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) recursive directory unlinker:

```
from pathlib import Path

def rmdir(directory):
    directory = Path(directory)
    for item in directory.iterdir():
        if item.is_dir():
            rmdir(item)
        else:
            item.unlink()
    directory.rmdir()

rmdir(Path("dir/"))
```

Comment: It suppose be better that shutil, thus shutil is asynchronous

Comment: Very nice, and a tangible example of recursion as a bonus.

Comment: Thats a very nice solution! In my use case, it was not supposed to throw an exception if the directory didn't exist so I also added a `if not directory.exists() return `  before iterating over the directories contents.

Comment: what is wrong with `shutil.rmtree(path)`?

Answer (score 37):

The default behavior of [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is to walk from root to leaf. Set `topdown=False` in `os.walk()` to walk from leaf to root.

Comment: what is wrong with `shutil.rmtree(path)`?

Answer (score 18):

Try `rmtree()` in [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) from the Python standard library

Comment: Does the `rmtree` deleted the entire directory? I guess it is similar to the one `rm -Rf $DIR`

Comment: from docs: "Delete an entire directory tree; path must point to a directory (but not a symbolic link to a directory). If ignore_errors is true, errors resulting from failed removals will be ignored; if false or omitted, such errors are handled by calling a handler specified by onerror or, if that is omitted, they raise an exception."

Answer (score 8):

better to use absolute path and import only the rmtree function
`from shutil import rmtree` 
as this is a large package the above line will only import the required function.

```
from shutil import rmtree
rmtree('directory-absolute-path')
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for the next guy searching for a micropython solution, this works purely based on os (listdir, remove, rmdir). It is neither complete (especially in errorhandling) nor fancy, it will however work in most circumstances.

```
def deltree(target):
    print("deltree", target)
    for d in os.listdir(target):
        try:
            deltree(target + '/' + d)
        except OSError:
            os.remove(target + '/' + d)

    os.rmdir(target)
```

Comment: what is wrong with `shutil.rmtree(path)`?

Answer (score 5):

The command (given by Tomek) **can't delete**  a file, if it  is **read only**. therefore, one can use -

```
import os, sys
import stat

def del_evenReadonly(action, name, exc):
    os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
    os.remove(name)

if  os.path.exists("test/qt_env"):
    shutil.rmtree('test/qt_env',onerror=del_evenReadonly)
```

Comment: when trying your code with my own folder to be deleted, I get an error saying:  `NameError: name 'stat' is not defined`. How has it been defined?

Comment: The stat module defines constants and functions for interpreting the results of os.stat(), os.fstat() and os.lstat(). what you can try : import os, sys
from stat import *

Answer (score 2):

The command `os.removedirs` is the tool for the job, if you are only looking for a single path to delete, e.g.:

```
os.removedirs("a/b/c/empty1/empty2/empty3")
```

will remove `empty1/empty2/empty3`, but leave a/b/c (presuming that c has some other contents).

```
    removedirs(name)
        removedirs(name)
        
        Super-rmdir; remove a leaf directory and all empty intermediate
        ones.  Works like rmdir except that, if the leaf directory is
        successfully removed, directories corresponding to rightmost path
        segments will be pruned away until either the whole path is
        consumed or an error occurs.  Errors during this latter phase are
        ignored -- they generally mean that a directory was not empty.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
def clear_folder(dir):
    if os.path.exists(dir):
        for the_file in os.listdir(dir):
            file_path = os.path.join(dir, the_file)
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    os.unlink(file_path)
                else:
                    clear_folder(file_path)
                    os.rmdir(file_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's **another pure-pathlib solution**, but *without* recursion:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union

def del_empty_dirs(base: Union[Path, str]):
    base = Path(base)
    for p in sorted(base.glob('**/*'), reverse=True):
        if p.is_dir():
            p.chmod(0o666)
            p.rmdir()
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(f'{p.parent} is not empty!')
    base.rmdir()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pythonic and recursion-less solution

```
>>> for e in sorted(p.rglob('**/*'), key=lambda v: v.is_dir()):
...     try:
...         e.unlink()
...     except IsADirectoryError:
...         e.rmdir()
```

The `rglob()` gives you all files and directories recursively in the path `p`. The `sorted()` with its `key` argument takes care that the result is ordered by files first and directories at the end. This makes it possible to make all directories empty with deleting their files first.

The `try...except...` part prevents you from using cheap `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `shutil.rmtree` is not enough when some directories are read-only. I ended up with this (tested on Mac-OS):

```
def rmtree(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return
    DIR_READ_WRITE = 0o700
    FILE_READ_WRITE = 0o600
    def remove_readonly(func, path, _):
        "Clear the readonly bit and reattempt the removal"
        os.chmod(path, FILE_READ_WRITE)
        func(path)

    # set all directories as read/write
    os.chmod(path, DIR_READ_WRITE)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for d in dirs:
            os.chmod(os.path.join(root, d), DIR_READ_WRITE)

    shutil.rmtree(path, onerror=remove_readonly)
```

Answer (score -1):

For Linux users, you can simply run the shell command in a pythonic way

```
import os
os.system("rm -r /home/user/folder1  /home/user/folder2  ...")
```

If facing any issue then instead of `rm -r` use `rm -rf`
but remember *f* will delete the directory forcefully.

Where `rm` stands for *remove*, `-r` for *recursively* and `-rf` for *recursively + forcefully*.

Note: It doesn't matter either the directories are empty or not, they'll get deleted.

Comment: when you use python however the code is system-dependent, it is no-longer pythonic.

Comment: @LukAron I've said, "shell command in a pythonic way" not only "pythonic way"