# PathLib recursively remove directory?

Tags: python, directory, pathlib

Is there any way to remove a directory and its contents in the PathLib module? With `path.unlink()` it only removes a file, with `path.rmdir()` the directory has to be empty. Is there no way to do it in one function call?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

As you already know, the only two `Path` methods for removing files/directories are `.unlink()` and `.rmdir()` and neither does what you want.

Pathlib is a module that provides object oriented paths across different OS's, it isn't meant to have lots of diverse methods.

> The aim of this library is to provide a simple hierarchy of classes to
> handle filesystem paths and the common operations users do over them.

The "uncommon" file system alterations, such as recursively removing a directory, is stored in different modules. If you want to recursively remove a directory, you should use the `shutil` module. (It works with `Path` instances too!)

```py
import shutil
import pathlib
import os  # for checking results

print(os.listdir())
# ["a_directory", "foo.py", ...]

path = pathlib.Path("a_directory")

shutil.rmtree(path)
print(os.listdir())
# ["foo.py", ...]
```

Comment: just for mention, can be done this way -https://stackoverflow.com/a/49782093/4249707

Comment: I still don’t get, why a recursive version is not part of pathlib.Path, when everything, what is needed is already there. I was really hoping, this confusing usage of os.path, os.mkdir, shutil, etc. would end with pathlib.

Comment: @SebastianWerk PR! PR! PR! -- although being in the stdlibrary it won't be out for a while sadly and would take a lot of effort to get in. I share your sentiments

Comment: what is wrong with doing `pth.rmdir()` if `pth` is a `Path` obj compared to your answer?

Comment: `path.rmdir()` will remove directory only if its empty

Comment: link to `shutil.rmtree` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

Comment: **I can tell you guys, why recursive directory removal is not part of Pathlib**: if you have a bug and instead of `/home/usr/my_proj/tmp_data` you remove `/home/usr/my_proj` you get the answer the hard way ;). I got pretty paranoid about that topic after a pretty intense experience I would not like to repeat. If you use formulations like this in your code on a regular basis, sooner or later you will get into the same situation.

Answer (score 19):

Otherwise, you can try this one if you want only `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def rm_tree(pth: Path):
    for child in pth.iterdir():
        if child.is_file():
            child.unlink()
        else:
            rm_tree(child)
    pth.rmdir()

rm_tree(your_path)
```

Comment: Is it safe to mutate the dir you're iterating over? Might have to extract the full results of the `iterdir()` to a list before starting to iterate.

Comment: The recursive function will continue removing files (child.unlink()) until the directory is empty. Once empty, the directory is removed (pth.rmdir()).

Answer (score 8):

Simple and effective:

```
def rmtree(f: Path):
    if f.is_file():
        f.unlink()
    else:
        for child in f.iterdir():
            rmtree(child)
        f.rmdir()
```

Answer (score 7):

You might use pathlib3x - it offers a backport of the latest (at the date of writing this answer Python 3.10.a0) Python pathlib for Python 3.6 or newer, and a few additional functions like `rmtree`

```
>>> python -m pip install pathlib3x

>>> import pathlib3x as pathlib

>>> my_path = pathlib.Path('c:/tmp/some_directory')
>>> my_path.rmtree(ignore_errors=True)
```

you can find it on [github](https://github.com/bitranox/pathlib3x) or [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib3x)

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of the pathlib3x library.</sup>

Comment: Will this `ignore_errors=True` help recursively remove the tree?

Comment: @nam-g-vu the parameter `ignore_errors=True` means that `my_path.rmtree(ignore_errors=True)` will not throw an exception if the path does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using a third-party library give [path](https://github.com/jaraco/path) a try.
Its API is similar to [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path), but provides some additional methods, including [`Path.rmtree()`](https://path.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#path.Path.rmtree) to recursively delete a directory tree.

Answer (score 5):

```
def rm_rf(basedir):
    if isinstance(basedir,str): basedir = pathlib.Path(basedir)
    if not basedir.is_dir(): return
    for p in reversed(list(basedir.rglob("*"))):
        if p.is_file(): p.unlink()
        elif p.is_dir(): p.rmdir()
    basedir.rmdir()
```

Comment: this does not look like it will remove non-empty subdirectories of basedir? The recursive answer from @maf88 looks better.